# Getting the return type of a function which uses generics

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

> Disclaimer: overly simplified functions follow, I'm aware they're
>   useless

```js
function thinger<T>(thing: T): T {
    return thing;
}

const thing = thinger({ a: "lol" });

thing.a;
```

The above code transpiles just fine. But I need to place result of `thinger<T>` into an object.

```
interface ThingHolder {
    thing: ReturnType<typeof thinger>;
}

const myThingHolder: ThingHolder = {
    thing: thinger({ a: "lol" }),
};
```

However I have lost my type information so `myThingHolder.thing.a` does not work

> Property 'a' does not exist on type '{}'

So I tried the following

```
interface ThingHolder<T> {
    thing: ReturnType<typeof thinger<T>>;
}

const myThingHolder: ThingHolder<{ a: string }> = {
    thing: thinger({ a: "lol" }),
};
```

But `typeof thinger<T>` is not valid typescript.

How can I get the return type of a function which has a different return type based on generics?

Comment: And what's wrong with figuring it out yourself?  `interface ThingHolder<T> { thing: T }` ?

Comment: As in my disclaimer at the beginning of my post, I realise in this overly simplified example I *should* do that, but my actual use case is not so simple. I have a function accepting many generics and returning something more complex than simply those generics (but the generics still affect the return type)

Comment: What in your complex case prevents you from writing out the complex type function of `T` explicitly?

Comment: I could write it, but it would be extremely verbose and require re-writing every time the function changes. To be honest, even if it *was* a reasonable solution, I would still like an answer to this question.

Comment: The short answer is going to be "TypeScript can't do that" because it has neither [generic values](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574), [higher kinded types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), nor [`typeof` on arbitrary expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606).

Comment: Why not make a type alias for your complicated type and use it both in the function definition and the interface property definition?

Comment: It isn't my function, it is a library's. I'm only interested in an answer to my question, which is a way to get the return type of a function whose return type is affected by generics. Alternatively an explanation as to why this is not possible would suffice. If it is not possible, I have simpler ways to resolve my use case. But if it is possible, I would prefer to do it that way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I might as well put this in an answer although it doesn't look like it will meet your needs.  TypeScript currently has neither [generic values](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574), [higher kinded types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), nor [`typeof` on arbitrary expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606). Generics in TypeScript are sort of "shallow" that way.  So as far as I know there's unfortunately no way to describe a type function that plugs type parameters into generic functions and checks the result:

```
// doesn't work, don't try it
type GenericReturnType<F, T> = F extends (x: T) => (infer U) ? U : never

function thinger<T>(thing: T): T {
  return thing;
}

// just {}, 
type ReturnThinger<T> = GenericReturnType<typeof thinger, T>;
```

---

So all I can do for you is suggest workarounds.  The most obvious workaround would be to use a type alias to describe what `thinger()` returns, and then use it multiple places.  This is a "backwards" version of what you want; instead of extracting the return type from the function, you build the function from the return type:

```
type ThingerReturn<T> = T; // or whatever complicated type you have

// use it here
declare function thinger<T>(thing: T): ThingerReturn<T>;

// and here
interface ThingHolder<T> {
  thing: ThingerReturn<T>;
}

// and then this works  
const myThingHolder: ThingHolder<{ a: string }> = {
  thing: thinger({ a: "lol" }),
};
```

Does that help?  I know it's not what you wanted, but hopefully it's at least a possible path forward for you.  Good luck!

Comment: Some interesting reads in the links you shared, thanks! Accepting answer as (with TS 2.8 at least) it does seem to be impossible :(

Comment: Actually I just posted a detailed solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60846777 which might help here as well.

Comment: Here I posted an alternative solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321419/typescript-returntype-of-generic-function/64840774#answer-64840774

Comment: Another relevant link tracking this issue:  https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37181

Comment: @jcalz should be possible soon. [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607)

Answer (score 1):

Probably this would solve the problem. But you need to create a fake class. It works because classes are types and JS-runtime objects at the same time.

```js
// generic function
// we want to get its result, but we cannot do it like
// ReturnType<typeof foo<T>()> // syntax error
const foo = <T,>(arg: T) => ({ test: arg });
// so, let's create a parametric class
class Wrapper<T> {
  // with the only method that uses our "foo"
  wrapped = (arg: T) => foo(arg);   
};
// due to the fact that class is a type we can use it as a type 
// with a generic parameter.
type GetFooResult<T> = ReturnType<Wrapper<T>['wrapped']>
type Bingo = GetFooResult<number>; // { test: number }
```

TS Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHMFMDtIJwJYGNQDMCu0kBcEHtoAoEUAd0jIENptRs8JJaFsBnUOSV9AG2wBpQAI3S1yoJNWh5aAEwYtQPBAGtIxMACUm6ONAAqATwAOkADzYTkPKjR48Z-QD4AFAEonoEq0M1KAD1B4ODw4QiQCVlpUe1AAXlBHfldKOHAALlB9N3jPFwBvOi5sTNTwUABfNwBuQg1QVjxBHiYAcnYkTkpsCkpQY1TKAFsmRBQkHkpWVnDJ6dAAdThKY1M4R098wlAvMFIWAAs6A4oCHkNQEewDvFlj7tB0Vi5QPF1QACIYvA-tsmXVpA7gkXGVMtlcnY8KC0jUdqBCBVavVZOgKPRjhRUJQcPdaBMpuwEOw%20pZTGQKJJoI9nqBFFNQKSrAiSPtrozGLAxv1Bld4AA6QhkigAcSYADF7NpuHwNvFQNpsLoDFYzEsVmsNgBtVqkAGmWStAC6TiFzIAQghoOAGAkxdhJXhpbxsGZoOghkJ4E5qrtQIUelFMu7PfBKkA). Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64919133/892741). Thx to @Colin