# TypeScript - ReturnType of a generic function not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

There is a feature in typescript called `ReturnType<TFunction>` which allows you to infer the return type of a particular function, like so

```
function arrayOf(item: string): string[] {
  return [item]
}
```

However, I am having trouble using it with generic functions:

```
function arrayOf<T>(item: T): T[] {
  return [item]
}

type R = ReturnType<typeof arrayOf> // R = {}[]
type R = ReturnType<typeof arrayOf<number>> // syntax error
// etc.
```

Using the top answer from [Typescript ReturnType of generic function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321419/typescript-returntype-of-generic-function), I have tried this: (by the way this is not a duplicate, it is different as the solution and question do apply to this case)

```
function arrayOf<T>(x: T): T[] {
  return [x];
}

type GenericReturnType<R, X> = X extends (...args: any[]) => R ? R : never;

type N = GenericReturnType<number, <T>(item: T) => T[]>; // N = never
```

I have also tried the following:

```
type GenericReturnType<TGenericParameter, TFunction> = TFunction extends (...args: any[]) => infer R ? R : never;

type N = GenericReturnType<number, <T>(item: T) => T[]>; // N = {}[]
```

as well as

```
type GenericReturnType<TGenericParameter, TFunction> = TFunction extends <T>(...args: any[]) => infer R ? R : never;

type N = GenericReturnType<number, <T>(item: T) => T[]>; // N = {}[]
```

and

```
type GenericReturnType<TGenericParameter, TFunction> = TFunction extends <T extends TGenericParameter>(...args: any[]) => infer R ? R : never;

type N = GenericReturnType<number, <T>(item: T) => T[]>; // N = {}[]
```

and also this

```
type GenericReturnType<TGenericParameter, TFunction> = TFunction extends (arg: TGenericParameter) => infer R ? R : never;

type N = GenericReturnType<number, <T>(item: T) => T[]>; // N = {}[]
```

and this

```
type GenericReturnType<TGenericParameter, TFunction> = TFunction extends <U extends TGenericParameter>(arg: U) => infer R ? R : never;

type N = GenericReturnType<number, <T>(item: T) => T[]>; // N = {}[]
```

as well as

```
type x = (<T>(item: T) => T[]) extends <T>(arg: T) => infer R ? R : never // x = {}[]
```

and finally

```
type x = (<T>(item: T) => T[]) extends (arg: number) => infer R ? R : never // x = {}[]
```

But none of them yield the much wanted type of `number[]`

So, my question is, is there any way to create something similar to the builtin `ReturnType` which works for functions with generic parameters, given the types of the generic parameters? (aka a solution to the above problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem as you and after countless workarounds not working, I found a somewhat "hack". However, this might not be convenient for all cases:

Similar to the answer given by Matt, the point is to have a dummy function, but without rewriting it. Instead of writing a dummy rewrite of your function, write a dummy function that returns a dummy usage of your function. Then, get the resulting type with `ReturnType`:

```
function arrayOf<T>(item: T): T[] {
    return [item];
}

const arrayOfNumber = () => arrayOf<number>(1);
type N = ReturnType<typeof arrayOfNumber>;
```

As of **TS 3.7**, unless I haven't done my research right, it still isn't possible to achieve the desired results without finding a workaround. Hopefully, we can get something that looks like this:

```
function arrayOf<T>(item: T): T[] {
    return [item];
}

type N = GenericReturnType<typeof arrayOf>; // N<T>
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the type arguments to the function, not currently, if you follow the chain of links to [Getting the return type of a function which uses generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50005595/getting-the-return-type-of-a-function-which-uses-generics).  Given the argument types, you can write a non-generic dummy function that passes arguments of those types and then check its return type:

```
function dummy(n: number) { return arrayOf(n); }
type N = ReturnType<typeof dummy>;
```