# TypeScript: Is it possible to get the return type of a generic function?

Tags: typescript, generics, typeof

I have exported a function from some module that looks like:

```
export function MyFunc<A>() {
    return {
        foo: (in: A) => void
    }
}
```

Now, in some other module, I want to be able to talk about the different return types of `MyFunc`. Since I didn't export the type, I'll use `typeof` to get hold of the type I want given the value `MyFunc`. **Ideally I would do the following**:

```
import { MyFunc } from "mymodule";
type MyFuncReturned<A> = ReturnType<typeof MyFunc<A>>;

function foo(): MyFuncReturned<string> {
   // ...
}
```

Hrmph, this doesn't work; `typeof` can only be passed a value and doesn't like my attempt to specify the generic type of that value.

The best I can do is convincing TypeScript to infer specific types of `MyFunc` from values I've created, and then giving them individual type aliases, eg:

```
const myFuncStringReturn = MyFunc<string>();
type MyFuncStringReturn = typeof myFuncStringReturn;
```

To avoid actually running `MyFunc` just to get the type info, I can hide it behind a function and use `ReturnType` on it:

```
const myFuncStringReturn = () => MyFunc<string>();
type MyFuncStringReturn = ReturnType<typeof myFuncStringReturn>;

const myFuncBoolReturn = () => MyFunc<bool>();
type MyFuncBoolReturn = ReturnType<typeof myFuncBoolReturn>;
```

This gives me a way of, one type at a time, talking about the different return types of `MyFunc`, but it

- Involves actual runtime code to be written that TS can infer from.
- Doesn't let me talk about `MyFunc` in a more generic sense.

The only "proper" solution I can come up with is duplicating a bunch of type info when I declare `MyFunc`:

```
export function MyFunc<A>(): MyFuncReturns<A> {
    return {
        foo: (in: A) => void
    }
}

export type MyFuncReturns<A> = {
    foo: (in: A) => void
}
```

But now as I change `MyFunc`, I have to make sure to keep `MyFuncReturns` in sync with it.

**Is there any way I can get hold of a type like `MyFuncReturns<A>` given just our exported value `MyFunc`, without having to add runtime code or add the boilerplate above?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a proposal to allow using `typeof` with arbitrary expressions to allow things like getting the return type of a generic functions for a specific type argument (see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26043) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606))

A more generic workaround that works today is to use a generic class with a field that is tied to the return type of the function. We can then extract the field of the class. Since for classes we can specify generic type parameters in type expressions we can extract the generic form of the return type:

```
export function MyFunc<A>() {
  return {
    foo: (os : A) => {}
  }
}

class Helper <T> {
  Return = MyFunc<T>()
}
type FuncReturnType<T> = Helper<T>['Return']
type ForBool = FuncReturnType<boolean> //  {foo: (os: boolean) => void;}
type ForString = FuncReturnType<string> //  {foo: (os: string) => void;}
```

**Note** If you have constraints of `A` you will need to duplicate those on `T` in `Helper` and `FuncReturnType`, that is unavoidable unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect! Looking at those proposals, better `typeof` support still sounds like it's a way off. This is one advantage of using classes over functions more for this sort of thing I suppose - you have the type information built in alongside them and don't have to resort to such hackery!

Comment: The links are outdated. #6606 has been closed because the scope was too broad. The new issue tracking that can be found under https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37181

Comment: SHould be possible to do without workarounds soon. [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607)

Comment: @captain-yossarian yup. we are all waiting for that one :)

Comment: I think it might be first step to higher kinded types. But I don't know how ts compiler works internally so it only my guessing

Answer (score 5):

It's a long time but TypeScript finally supported it. Since v4.7 (still in beta as of this writing), with the help of **Instantiation Expressions** feature we can now do this:

```js
function myFunc<A>() {
  return {
    foo: (a: A) => { }
  }
}

type MyFuncReturnType<A> = ReturnType<typeof myFunc<A>>;

const a: MyFuncReturnType<string> = {
  foo: (a) => {
    console.log(a.toUpperCase());
  }
};

const b: MyFuncReturnType<number> = {
  foo: (a) => {
    console.log(a.toFixed(2));
  }
};
```

I created [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.0-dev.20220408&ssl=19&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFwQDwEEB8AFAJSIDeAsAFCKIBOAplCHUpTbYsHHAFyKEAhv1ykAvPnKIAvtVqyqC6lFQAHBogCyGLACUmLMABU1DPJLGJ9zVifXYV6uMBQ7I5-AG5q1CAgDOUIjCWm4Q1oZ2ZoF0MGAA5hbkclw8-ELikuyciH5g-nAANgwAdIVw8UIlUHAAqqrqdADCgv4MJMTeHArSXb4BQQBG-NqYkBG2pthgIMiDDHRJ2al8AoKZyRy0eQXFZRVVNegwAB4MACaEAEzEnSk9XUA) so people can play with it. See [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7-beta/#instantiation-expressions) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607) for more information.

Comment: Awesome! I was using this myself but I'm getting an eslint error (in `myFunc` right after `typeof`, in your example) for some reason. I've updated my @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin and @typescript-eslint/parser to 5.39.0 but I'm still getting the Parsing error: '>' expected.eslint error. Got any tips?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it. I had TypeScript 4.6.4 installed (package.json), but I was using VSCode's version inside the editor, which is 4.8.4. That's why I wasn't getting a TypeScript error, but I was getting an eslint error.

Answer (score 4):

[Titian's solution above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52964723) works great if the Generic is only applied inside the function body.

However, there are cases that **the Generic Type is a part of the arguments and/or return type.** e.g.

```
function MyFunc3<T extends object | number | string>(r: number, p: T, x: boolean): T {
    return p;
}
```

So, to generalize Titian's solution and support fixating both the arguments and the return type of any generic function, I wrote the following:

#### Required Utility Types

```
// From https://stackoverflow.com/a/53808212 by jcalz (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218)
export type IfEquals<T, U, Y=unknown, N=never> =
    (<G>() => G extends T ? 1 : 2) extends
    (<G>() => G extends U ? 1 : 2) ? Y : N;

// Aidin: Please comment if you could make the following shorter!
type ReplaceType<T, FROM_TYPE, TO_TYPE> = IfEquals<T, FROM_TYPE, TO_TYPE, T>;
type ReplaceTypeInArray<ARR, F, T> =
    ARR extends [] ? []
    : ARR extends [infer P0] ? [P0 extends F ? T : P0]
    : ARR extends [infer P0, infer P1] ? [ReplaceType<P0, F, T>, ReplaceType<P1, F, T>]
    : ARR extends [infer P0, infer P1, infer P2] ? [ReplaceType<P0, F, T>, ReplaceType<P1, F, T>, ReplaceType<P2, F, T>]
    : ARR extends [infer P0, infer P1, infer P2, infer P3] ? [ReplaceType<P0, F, T>, ReplaceType<P1, F, T>, ReplaceType<P2, F, T>, ReplaceType<P3, F, T>]
    : ARR extends [infer P0, infer P1, infer P2, infer P3, infer P4] ? [ReplaceType<P0, F, T>, ReplaceType<P1, F, T>, ReplaceType<P2, F, T>, ReplaceType<P3, F, T>, ReplaceType<P4, F, T>]
    : ARR extends [infer P0, infer P1, infer P2, infer P3, infer P4, infer P5] ? [ReplaceType<P0, F, T>, ReplaceType<P1, F, T>, ReplaceType<P2, F, T>, ReplaceType<P3, F, T>, ReplaceType<P4, F, T>, ReplaceType<P5, F, T>]
    : ARR extends [infer P0, infer P1, infer P2, infer P3, infer P4, infer P5, infer P6] ? [ReplaceType<P0, F, T>, ReplaceType<P1, F, T>, ReplaceType<P2, F, T>, ReplaceType<P3, F, T>, ReplaceType<P4, F, T>, ReplaceType<P5, F, T>, ReplaceType<P6, F, T>]
    : ARR extends [infer P0, infer P1, infer P2, infer P3, infer P4, infer P5, infer P6, infer P7] ? [ReplaceType<P0, F, T>, ReplaceType<P1, F, T>, ReplaceType<P2, F, T>, ReplaceType<P3, F, T>, ReplaceType<P4, F, T>, ReplaceType<P5, F, T>, ReplaceType<P6, F, T>, ReplaceType<P7, F, T>]
    : ARR extends [infer P0, infer P1, infer P2, infer P3, infer P4, infer P5, infer P6, infer P7, infer P8] ? [ReplaceType<P0, F, T>, ReplaceType<P1, F, T>, ReplaceType<P2, F, T>, ReplaceType<P3, F, T>, ReplaceType<P4, F, T>, ReplaceType<P5, F, T>, ReplaceType<P6, F, T>, ReplaceType<P7, F, T>, ReplaceType<P8, F, T>]
    : never;
```

#### Sample Functions

```
type ALL = string | number | object | boolean;

export function MyFunc1<T extends ALL>() {
  return {
    foo: (os : T) => {}
  }
}

function MyFunc2<T extends ALL>(r: 55, p: T, x: boolean): T {
    return p;
}
```

#### Fixation examples

```
// Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/52964723 by Titian (https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734)
class Helper1 <T extends ALL> {
    Fixate = (...args: ReplaceTypeInArray<Parameters<typeof MyFunc1>, ALL, T>) => MyFunc1<T>(...args);
}
type FixatedFunc1<T extends ALL> = Helper1<T>['Fixate'];

// -- Usage

type ForNumber1 = FixatedFunc1<number> //  {foo: (os: number) => void;}
type ForString1 = FixatedFunc1<string> //  {foo: (os: string) => void;}

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

class Helper2 <T extends ALL> {
    Fixate = (...args: ReplaceTypeInArray<Parameters<typeof MyFunc2>, ALL, T>) => MyFunc2<T>(...args);
}
type FixatedFunc2<T extends ALL> = Helper2<T>['Fixate'];

// -- Usage

type ForNumber2 = FixatedFunc2<number> //  (args_0: 55, args_1: number, args_2: boolean) => number
type ForString2 = FixatedFunc2<string> //  (args_0: 55, args_1: string, args_2: boolean) => string
```

[Playground Link (Contains all 3 parts)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=60&pc=99#code/FAehAID9p2-hi6ggMQE4HsC24AWALgQA4DOAXGKQQIYDGA1pgG4Cm6AZgDaYDuAdHRwgaIAKwBmABwAGKQCYAjPPAAjAJ7gAVnRpcAXuAAUhEhSq1GLdtz6DhAV1LtSIeVKkB2JVICUwVgAPYkx0AnACdWJWcABJDgBRAEcHPVIAHgAVABpwAFVcgE0AXgcAOwYyvjLcgDlistY2dAA+cGLgAEgjdIBxFqNfdrbe8CCCVjKAE1JwTPAAfnBFcHJweSHxyZmunv7B4fBRrenZvMXl1fWhpcKr2oBuYBRwAEEASyn3srWABS5WDRnOAhNhsJNwu8OOB1JgHCC4VwpuBsDQGDECHgYhxMFweLxvgBzcCkPChCboACEwEi0XAACVWMQuPRWJkoqwsrlUPSAPIAWQA+plCr8ErlMrzhaKEm1inFEik0lzwDyBdKxRKpSLNXMWk9aTFGczWezorEyq90OgaOp0q96fTuRK5cBwO63o6xoEJqdwABtAC6FyDbo9awd9O9vpmAe+HHY4F+MmDS39yej21mqAu8z+KbD7ojXpOsf98cTydyFfQScUqYDxpZdDZHPSVdVLtyTdNbd+imdesDhaukczfvLZQTtY7Nbr1anlfkDf9PZbZs5HdQXYZTObrei7YHnb13b3vcPv3kg8yLWHHtHJZ9Wbji5nMgX0-n4DnV8-lYkFc1wPTcPxPW8zxNdc+2PbdT13KCQPba9wJaSD9w3dsJBvO8R2LKNS1mScv1nN9v1-FDf2wn8yN+AAWIDz2gy8wLgiCEIwmCcPQi9NxQti0I43isO4oTmM3OicPvcNPQI58J1-MDf2PCj-xnajf0kmiSLERjEMwrcd2AgzYKMpikL-VCePEkSrLEiytIE6yLLEKS8Nk8cy0UtTyNoyjaI02itN-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-DoFlSFmAAJVguGidAVlD+TY3D3XM5HVB3kCGgJnpow-AgE0HQISCgmUOQWitDaO0vwQE0HBBSDIhpMDQlVurP2ihBLvxdM7No6CNZZAGEA-gICwG+ELjSDkqof5-1YFMDBdBNbzDDhHemd8H7sGYS0f0AByb+v8Ji8MDPDYuABaMR+RSA0EJKwKm1DUChFqBzLmT96YCLoQwwhZQVHsDaMXTO1tbb2zWDozm7A8HgGYJgT4DwPbU0UegFGjMiQrHlBoiYWjMHpGoEzMohJ9EQEMaLYx4DfFEksdY2xRcID12QMAS+QJb730fioF+MZZjv1dl-Wh-95SAOAaA8BhUoHWltO2eBiCXDpBQWgoOft5DYNprgw4BCGlEIKaQopFDgD2IUbk+hjCQ4sNfpkth8oOGpKIXwjxrBhGiIgBIqRMi5FULpI45R5j0AqHcQMrxdAQ5mNUYE90RgyGkEFDIaOoVzmCkUKY3R6Bci3PkEnUWAJU6WKOewNZMRHHOL8YSHZNDBGDODj4lx-iTnGFuVc8AMdnlFLuWscJ-jEVgMFK8tQ7zxaWNRYSIAA)

Now, one can simply use `ReturnType<T>` or `Parameteres<T>` on any of these fixated function types!

Comment: You can write `ReplaceTypeInArray` like: `type ReplaceTypeInArray<ARR extends unknown[], F, T> = { [K in keyof ARR]: Replace<ARR[K], F, T>; };`

Comment: You can also remove the `ALL` type and just use `unknown` instead.

Comment: Also, removing the constraint on `ARR` from `ReplaceTypeInArray` altogether would allow it to _just work_ on object types -- or any type -- as well. i.e. `type ReplaceTypeIn<T, FROM, TO> = { [K in keyof T]: Replace<T[K], FROM, TO>; };`

Comment: @tim.stasse thanks for your comments.  I am not sure what `Replace<>` is in your comments.  Nonetheless, I am pretty sure that writing your own solution with a Playground Link would make it easier to follow and also easier to digest for other people.

Comment: `Replace` was meant to be `ReplaceType`. Unfortunately, the Playground Link is too long to fit in a comment though.

Comment: @tim.stasse 
I meant an "answer", not a comment.  If you can get rid of my pyramid of `ReplaceTypeInArray` that would definitely worth being an answer on its own!

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Aidin's answer, I've managed to make `ReplaceTypeIn`, which works for any number of elements, objects as well as arrays, and uses only a couple of lines:

```js
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Derived from https://stackoverflow.com/a/53808212 by jcalz (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218)
export type IfEquals<T, U, Y=unknown, N=never> =
    (<G>() => G extends T ? 1 : 2) extends
    (<G>() => G extends U ? 1 : 2) ? Y : N;

type ReplaceType<T, FROM_TYPE, TO_TYPE> = IfEquals<T, FROM_TYPE, TO_TYPE, T>;
type ReplaceTypeIn<T, FROM_TYPE, TO_TYPE> = {
  [K in keyof T]: ReplaceType<T[K], FROM_TYPE, TO_TYPE>;
};

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ SAMPLE FUNCTIONS ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

export function MyFunc1<T extends unknown>() {
  return {
    foo: (os: T) => {}
  }
}

function MyFunc2<T extends unknown>(r: 55, p: T, x: boolean): T {
    return p;
}

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ FIXATIONS ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

// Derived from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52964723 by Titian (https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734)
class Helper1 <T extends unknown> {
    Fixate = (...args: ReplaceTypeIn<Parameters<typeof MyFunc1>, unknown, T>) => MyFunc1<T>(...args);
}
type FixatedFunc1<T extends unknown> = Helper1<T>['Fixate'];

// -- Usage

type ForNumber1 = FixatedFunc1<number> //  {foo: (os: number) => void;}
type ForString1 = FixatedFunc1<string> //  {foo: (os: string) => void;}

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

class Helper2 <T extends unknown> {
    Fixate = (...args: ReplaceTypeIn<Parameters<typeof MyFunc2>, unknown, T>) => MyFunc2<T>(...args);
}
type FixatedFunc2<T extends unknown> = Helper2<T>['Fixate'];

// -- Usage

type ForNumber2 = FixatedFunc2<number> //  (r: 55, p: number, x: boolean) => number
type ForString2 = FixatedFunc2<string> //  (r: 55, p: string, x: boolean) => string
```

Here's a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAehAID9p2-hi6ggEQKYCcCWA3dAJuAGaYD2AtuABYAutADgM4BcYTtAhgMYDWZ%20TMQA2ZAO4A6bpRCcQAVgDMADgAMygEwBGDeABGAT3AArbp2EAvcAAo6jVuy58BWEeKkyArkyxMQG5WUAdm1lAEpgdAAPBjJMWnBaAwZ0cABJYgBRAEdPcyYAHgAVABpwAFUygE0AXk8AO1568XqygDka%20vRBAD5wGuAASGsCgHEe6zD%20vtHwaNp0eoImcCLwAH5wLXAWcA0p%20cXloZHxyenwWcOllfKNrZ29qc2qx7aAbmBgJJTwACV0AxhDx0EVkuhimUAGJ-ADyAFkAPpFKoABUyZSKsORaMyfRq6SyuXykPAMIROPRmOxKKpqx6nx%20qQBQJBYJSaXqpPJSNpGNWNNx%20PAAG9gOBwABtADS4Gw9XAvHQBjIxFWAF1dizgdxQeDijL1dC4bzcdTKXjPgBfT4oKBIB3QcAAZQAgvDUQAZTJk8ptADCRTSsLazvtjvgX2isXiJAa3Fo2DICvhBih8a0xTmUQWN3ADSaLQmUzFEsw6FonkwCtLEpIZDIu2sZFYqymNT6Iqt4vA3e7wGI8cTyfAqfT9W4Giz12W%20cazTE9QmmF28nkZQYu1K4Ciuz0DeE6E49TCW9FPbLFarCoY1q%20YHDEfgZLSAA1XUGQ2Gnwh72gsHghAkOQVB2MwbAgBwPD8IIbiSNIFCyAoGgAJwAGwACwhIo%20hGEU2CJseNhgQ4kFODBriiPBXg%20Jgfg6PIQSKBhETcMCTArAAEugwgpJg2zTjmRwrAWC5LuedZktgUScAs-Q2BIimcJgADmrbamy4KcgUqLKZwFAVr4BRMqqo5phmPRlKJLSYj07Z9GOGbFBMikSMpalhHeTJSTJCwEOO3CZmsM4ifORbydxvFYEFPSSgA5FC0myegcXqraD4ALQZRUTCcCp6BfN5UJxG0ngUHo0XyYlvmEAFmb1GVFWYH0D6isQDZNi2uwNeVWD2eAuBkNgBDvN2RVxM6tA4PUKnbAS1XJf5TkcNNKktRAbUdTYXXgCt8oqf1g3DaNf6Pj%20kBfGxnAceAkV8bogm5rO1mLp2F4%20cl8nWK57nqYCOp6hyXK6Zg%20mGXRxngqZjkThollzoWi62f1MOTs531KapTCecAY3gh9fkBVOwVCXmL3iQSd1YMTsUJUlCypelEBZTleUFd8%20PFZgpW9ZgujzfTtXxlOPVNetErWCu4Brhu3WNVgZS7voB5HieFyi1gHO-Fzk2rfzBNC7DBR7TN4s2FLMvgJuu1Tftit7irx79SbKnAEAA) for the example above.