# How to test if two types are exactly the same

Tags: typescript

Here is my first attempt: ([playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F**%20Trigger%20a%20compiler%20error%20when%20a%20value%20is%20_not_%20an%20exact%20type.%20*%2F%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20exactType%3A%20%3CT%2C%20U%20extends%20T%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20draft%3F%3A%20U%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20expected%3F%3A%20T%0D%0A)%20%3D%3E%20T%20extends%20U%20%3F%20T%20%3A%201%20%26%200%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20let%20a%3A%20any%5B%5D%0D%0Adeclare%20let%20b%3A%20%5Bnumber%5D%5B%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%24ExpectError%0D%0AexactType(a%2C%20b)%0D%0A))

```
/** Trigger a compiler error when a value is _not_ an exact type. */
declare const exactType: <T, U extends T>(
    draft?: U,
    expected?: T
) => T extends U ? T : 1 & 0

declare let a: any[]
declare let b: [number][]

// $ExpectError
exactType(a, b)
```

Related: https://github.com/gcanti/typelevel-ts/issues/39

Comment: Just curious, why would you do that? Any use case?

Comment: @muradm For testing [ambient type definitions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html)

Comment: As typescript uses structural-type-system, I'm having trouble understanding the reasoning of this type of assertions. Could you, please, elaborate on your case?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Ah, the *type-level equality operator* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#27024](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024).  @MattMcCutchen has come up with a solution, described in [a comment on that issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024#issuecomment-421529650) involving generic conditional types which does a decent job of detecting when two types are exactly equal, as opposed to just mutually assignable.  In a perfectly sound type system, "mutually assignable" and "equal" would probably be the same thing, but TypeScript isn't perfectly sound.  In particular, the [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) type is both assignable to and assignable from any other type, meaning that `string extends any ? true : false` and `any extends string ? true: false` both evaluate to `true`, despite the fact that `string` and `any` are not the same type.

Here's an `IfEquals<T, U, Y, N>` type which evaluates to `Y` if `T` and `U` are equal, and `N` otherwise.

```
type IfEquals<T, U, Y=unknown, N=never> =
  (<G>() => G extends T ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<G>() => G extends U ? 1 : 2) ? Y : N;
```

Let's see it work:

```
type EQ = IfEquals<any[], [number][], "same", "different">; // "different"
```

Okay, those are recognized as different types.  There are probably some other edge cases where two types that you think are the same are seen as different, and vice versa:

```
type EQ1 = IfEquals<
  { a: string } & { b: number },
  { a: string, b: number },
  "same", "different">; // "different"!

type EQ2 = IfEquals<
  { (): string, (x: string): number },
  { (x: string): number, (): string },
  "same", "different">; // "different", as expected, but:

type EQ3 = IfEquals<
  { (): string } & { (x: string): number },
  { (x: string): number } & { (): string },
  "same", "different">; // "same"!! but they are not the same, 
// intersections of functions are order-dependent
```

---

Anyway, given this type we can make a function that generates an error unless the two types are equal in this way:

```
/** Trigger a compiler error when a value is _not_ an exact type. */
declare const exactType: <T, U>(
  draft: T & IfEquals<T, U>,
  expected: U & IfEquals<T, U>
) => IfEquals<T, U>

declare let a: any[]
declare let b: [number][]

// $ExpectError
exactType(a, b) // error
```

Each argument has a type `T` or `U` (for type inference of the generic parameter) intersected with `IfEquals<T, U>` so that there will be an error unless `T` and `U` are equal.  This gives the behavior you want, I think.

Note that the arguments of this function are not optional.  I don't really know why you wanted them to be optional, but (at least with `--strictNullChecks` turned on) it weakens the check to do so:

```
declare let c: string | undefined
declare let d: string
exactType(c, d) // no error if optional parameters!
```

It's up to you if that matters.

Comment: This knowledge will help millions of people. Thanks @jcalz!

Comment: Why is `expected: U & IfEquals<T, U>` necessary? I think `draft: T & IfEquals<T, U>` catches all the errors.

Comment: I simplified it to this: https://gist.github.com/aleclarson/a5e5efefb907a22aef64a00f8d7c7416

Comment: I think if you replace `U & IfEquals<T, U>` with just `U` then `exactType()` will accept arguments where `T` is `never` and `U` is something else, and I assumed you wanted that to be excluded.

Comment: Your solution fails when comparing `any[]` with `ReadonlyArray<any>` (see here: bit.ly/2TNxPop). I've updated the gist above with a solution that catches this.

Comment: Could somebody explain me why we use extra  <G>() => G extends T   helper? Just don't understand it

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine this comment on the linked github issue explains it: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024#issuecomment-510924206

Comment: Should `{ a: string } & { b: number }` and `{ a: string, b: number }` be considered the same?

Comment: ``In a perfectly sound type system, "mutually assignable" and "equal" would probably be the same thing`` maybe you meant nominal-type-system X structural-type-system here?

Answer (score 11):

#### edit: The most refined version can be found [here](https://github.com/aleclarson/spec.ts/blob/master/index.d.ts)

Here's the most robust solution I've found thus far:

```
// prettier-ignore
type Exact<A, B> = (<T>() => T extends A ? 1 : 0) extends (<T>() => T extends B ? 1 : 0)
    ? (A extends B ? (B extends A ? unknown : never) : never)
    : never

/** Fails when `actual` and `expected` have different types. */
declare const exactType: <Actual, Expected>(
    actual: Actual & Exact<Actual, Expected>,
    expected: Expected & Exact<Actual, Expected>
) => Expected
```

Thanks to @jcalz for pointing in the right direction!

Comment: fails for Exact<1, 1>

Answer (score 9):

I wrote a library, [tsafe](https://github.com/garronej/tsafe), that lets you do that.

[image]

Thank @jcalz, your answer helped a lot in making this possible!

Comment: [Please replace images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for a pure typescript solution without any third-party library dependency, this one should work for you

```
export function assert<T extends never>() {}
type TypeEqualityGuard<A,B> = Exclude<A,B> | Exclude<B,A>;
```

And usage like

```
assert<TypeEqualityGuard<{var1: string}, {var1:number}>>(); // returns an error
assert<TypeEqualityGuard<{var1: string}, {var1:string}>>(); // no error
```

Answer (score 4):

I was a bit annoyed that the other propositions imply that I only get `false` without any detail to understand why it is failing.

This is how I solved it for my use case (and it gives readable errors):

```
type X = { color: string };
type Y = { color: string };
type Z = { color: number };

const assert = <A, B extends A, C extends B>() => {}

/** Pass! */
assert<X, Y, X>(); 

/**
 * Fail nicely:
 * Type 'Z' does not satisfy the constraint 'X'.
 * Types of property 'color' are incompatible.
 * Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
 */
assert<X, Z, X>();
```

Answer (score 2):

The most robust `Equals` that I've seen so far (though still not perfect) is this one:

```js
type Equals<A, B> = _HalfEquals<A, B> extends true ? _HalfEquals<B, A> : false;

type _HalfEquals<A, B> = (
    A extends unknown
        ? (
              B extends unknown
                  ? A extends B
                      ? B extends A
                          ? keyof A extends keyof B
                              ? keyof B extends keyof A
                                  ? A extends object
                                      ? _DeepHalfEquals<A, B, keyof A> extends true
                                          ? 1
                                          : never
                                      : 1
                                  : never
                              : never
                          : never
                      : never
                  : unknown
          ) extends never
            ? 0
            : never
        : unknown
) extends never
    ? true
    : false;

type _DeepHalfEquals<A, B extends A, K extends keyof A> = (
    K extends unknown ? (Equals<A[K], B[K]> extends true ? never : 0) : unknown
) extends never
    ? true
    : false;
```

It fails for `Equals<[any, number], [number, any]>`, for example.

found here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024#issuecomment-845655557

Answer (score -4):

We should take different approaches depending on the problem. For example, if we know that we're comparing numbers with any, we can use `typeof()`.

If we're comparing interfaces, for example, we can use this approach:

```
function instanceOfA(object: any): object is A {
    return 'member' in object;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, these types are _not_ meant for code that will be executed. It's just for testing ambient type definitions. At least my use case is.