# Creating a TypeScript construct that throws an error if two types are not equal

Tags: typescript, generics

I need to create an `enforceTypeEquality` construct that takes two types and throws a TS error if they are not equal.

```
type T1 = { name: string, age: number };
type T2 = { name: string, age: number, color: string };
type T3 = { name: "alice" | "bob", age: number };

type _T1 = { name: string, age: number };

// Ideally it should be a generic function:
enforceTypeEquality<T1, T1>(); // does nothing
enforceTypeEquality<T1, _T1>(); // does nothing
enforceTypeEquality<T1, T2>(); // throws an error
enforceTypeEquality<T1, T3>(); // throws an error
enforceTypeEquality<T2, T3>(); // throws an error

// But might as well be a generic type:
type A = EnforceTypeEquality<T1, T1>; // does nothing
type B = EnforceTypeEquality<T1, T2>; // throws an error

// Or anything else that's necessary to make it work
```

Is it possible to make such construct?

I am working with Create React App and I would also settle for a solution that results in any other compile error.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807517/how-to-test-if-two-types-are-exactly-the-same)

Comment: Compile time error is the only thing you will get with just types. Type information does not get transpiled into javascript unless you are using something like reflect-metadata together with decorators, which is experimental.

Comment: When you say TypeError, you specifically mean at runtime?  No, that will never happen.  Consider that both `enforceTypeEquality<T1, T1>()` and `enforceTypeEquality<T1, T2>()` will be emitted as the JavaScript code `enforceTypeEquality()`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for @bugs, thank you! This answers my question.

Comment: My bad Mirco and jcalz, when I said TypeError, I meant the error my TS compiler emits during compile type... That's what I thought TypeError was, but it's not, TypeError is a type of runtime error. What I actually meant is calleded TypeScript error in my console. I will correct my question.