# Check for exhaustive in a builder pattern

Tags: typescript

I want to build something like this:

```
type MyValues = "good" | "bad" | "ugly"

function doSomething(values:MyValues) {
   return startBuilder(values)
          .case("good", 1)
          .case("bad", 2)
          .exhaustive() // this should give an compiler error, since I forgot the `ugly` }
```

I tried to figure out the `tail` using TypeScript's `infer` - but with no luck:

```
type Extract<T, A> = A extends T
  ? T extends infer Tail
    ? Tail
    : never
  : never;
type X = Extract<Values, 'good'>;
```

But this does not work. Any ideas?

Here is a playground: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-mguypt

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WkG69W) work for you? It errors with a message hinting at it, too.

Comment: It does indeed . Thank you very much!!! Can you elaborate on this a bit so I am able to understand your solution?

Comment: I guess this is already answered, but if you don't want to allow duplicates (no `.case("bad",1).case("bad",2)` for example) then [this version](https://tsplay.dev/Na1MyN) might be more straightforward.  I'll write it up if it meets your needs.  Let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We'll first need a type that checks if two types are EXACTLY equal, a simple `extends` won't do the trick here:

```
type Equals<A, B> = (<T>() => T extends A ? true : false) extends (<T>() => T extends B ? true : false) ? true : false;
```

The explanation behind why this interesting-looking type works can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807517/how-to-test-if-two-types-are-exactly-the-same) by jcalz no less.

Then we define the Builder class:

```
class Builder<T, SoFar extends ReadonlyArray<unknown> = []> {
    private cases = new Map<T, unknown>();
}
```

It takes a generic `T` which is what it will check its cases against, and a generic not intended to be passed by the end user. This generic `SoFar` stores which cases have been used *so far*.

So let's build the `case` function now:

```
    case<V extends T>(v: V, d: unknown): Builder<T, [...SoFar, V]> {
        this.cases.set(v, d);

        return this as Builder<T, [...SoFar, V]>;
    }
```

It takes something that extends `T` and any value, then returns the builder as `Builder<T, [...SoFar, V]>`, which means we add the case to the cases used up so far.

Finally in here:

```
    exhaustive(...args: Equals<T, SoFar[number]> extends true ? [] : [{ error: "Builder is not exhaustive." }]) {

    }
```

We check if `T` and `SoFar[number]` are exactly the same. If they are, then we have exhausted all cases. Otherwise, we say that we expect a parameter.

Because you will likely call `exhaustive` with no parameters, calling it without using up all cases will display a nice error message for the user.

You can even go one step further and include all the missing cases in the error message! The second playground link demonstrates this.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogjgVwIYBsDOAeAggGigIQD4oBeKACgwBVDyBKU4qqCAD2AgDsATNKLKAH4owAE4JoALigAzVGggM2HHn0o16jKM2VdeBISPFTZ8xYbESo0ueggBuALAAoFwGMUSNH3wIAlijcEKLUeADKAPYAYkiiLOx6fABKEEjcEZwoIFiiokggGAicANacEQDunMRkANoAusQA3i5QrVBgon4AbkgcUG5eEHxknBDlUACySGChUEWlFVX0Tq7Obf2DGABq8Sr6Gl3SW3jc0vNllXTSvgFBIVR4NQB0L5ExonhbDVDNa+ttwAAFn40E8BgpQQpgOQuic6CsWv9WqIIMAEKJOCJgXwvAR-IFgrNnq9orFPg0VusAL4uRGtNiApAINDAboQcgvJ6xADmaGk8GQ6Fmb1iNU4CAAtgAjYLfXSqIxWYT1axQGqNFi5CKiaQAIhuBLiIKgZWA8UZzNZXQgT11UCpdQYvzp9pcNNWMiKblZGSgLNiwGotCdUBRaIxJrGeNuhI08Ndq1AkCgW1QEmGUAA5NyIhFuJmoAAfLNStIF4uZhDcrKZhHONwZFmyXOkP3AAPbNNDYOIsGDcjZ3P5vAARjovfB7MzpeHUAATOO-k8GUyWWzlrTVg3OE3S3EyP7RIHUyh0z2l5OBzm85nR4vWn2FAOZ7f5-eoI+p1Wa3gAMzv5dWAtNdrQ3ZwgA)

[Playground with error messages that display missing cases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogjgVwIYBsDOAeAggGigIQD4oBeKACgwBVDyBKU4qqCAD2AgDsATNKLKAH4owAE4JoALigAzVGggM2HHn0o16jKM2VdeBISPFTZ8xYbESo0ueggBuALAAoFwGMUSNH3wIAlijcEKLUeADKAPYAYkiiLOx6fABKEEjcEZwoIFiiokggGAicANacEQDunMRkANoAusQA3i5QrVBgon4AbkgcUG5eEHxknBDlUACySGChUEWlFVX0Tq7Obf2DGABq8Sr6Gl3SW3jc0vNllXTSvgFBIVR4NQB0L5ExonhbDVDNa+ttwAAFn40E8BgpQQpgOQuic6CsWv9WqIIMAEKJOCJgXwvAR-IFgrNnq9orFPg0VusAL4uRGtNiApAINDAboQcgvJ6xADmaGk8GQ6Fmb1iNU4CAAtgAjYLfXSqIxWYT1axQGqNFi5CKiaQAIhuBLiIKgZWA8UZzNZXQgT119igEpBaD8nG5-NYHgQQWFpNEYslMtE3ypdQYvzpUBpzijLhkRTcrIyUBZsWA1FoYagKLRGJNYzxt0JGnhkdpzlAkCgW1QEmGUAA5NyIhFuPWoAAfBtStJtzv1hDcrK9hsdVGgesI5xuDIs2TN0jJ4Cp7Y1oYZxFgwbkRvN1t4ACMdA34PZ9e7e6gACYj38ngymSy2csy+4Z2bu3EyCnRGnqyha+ut4ntuTYtvWB43q0m4KNu57gVekFQNBp4DkOeAAMyIch26jsA454AALFh96Wk+8IuEAA)

Comment: Can you explain why `extends` doesn't work?  (Can't you check `[T] extends [SoFar[number]]`?) And do you care about the order of the cases?  (Can't you just have `SoFar` be a union instead of an array type?) Compare to [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WzOrRw) of your solution.