# Testing expected typescript's type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to statically type check some types for a [library](https://github.com/TakitoTech/schemez).

I'm using

```
export type Expect<T extends E, E> = T extends E ? true : false;
```

and its working for most tests. However, if I try testing the following:

```
type TypeA = {
    prop1: {
        str: string;
    };
    prop2?: {
        str: string;
    };
}

type TypeB = {
    prop1: {
        str: string;
    };
    prop2?: {
        str?: string; // different from TypeA
    }
}

type _Check = Expect<TypeA, TypeB>; // No error why?
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCi5gGMYB4AqcoMwAdgCYDO6ANOgHxwC8chxZV6cA-AlAK6oAXHABmAQwA2lYAG4AUPKQpWyYAEFmcAN7yAkGCgQwARhG69eyjCgjrUAJakA5gr0BfN4eMAmbuf0rGzsbJ1d9T3l3RWVUfDUAIS0Lb1MAy3sQxxc3SIMjMD90oKh-OHsw2TgAemq4cgdRUWAoMnhRIwBbVRR1CKiYtTgAfQBhAAtsAGstDBQcAjV1OniUBPoq2rgAOQgiKCMoOAB3ccRuIA)

TypeA equals TypeB (ie no error is reported).

1. Why is there no error when comparing TypeA with TypeB
2. How to deep check that the types are equal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test if two types are exactly the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807517/how-to-test-if-two-types-are-exactly-the-same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export type Expect<T, E> = T extends E ? E extends T? true : false: false

type TypeA = {
    prop1: {
        str: string;
    };
    prop2?: {
        str: string;
    };
}

type TypeB = {
    prop1: {
        str: string;
    };
    prop2?: {
        str?: string; // different from TypeA
    }
}

const isTrue=<T extends true>()=>{}

isTrue<Expect<TypeA, TypeB>>() // expect error
isTrue<Expect<TypeA, TypeA>>() // ok
```

[image]
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=37&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCi5gGMYB4AqANOgHxwC8c%20coMwAdgCYDO6cA-G7Qy1ZzFACuqAFxwAZgEMANs2Bips4AFgAUGqQoqyYAEEKcAN5q4puGCgQwARjHHVZx3GYCxLqAEt6AcwDcJswBffwczCysAJnY7AKdnV3jPHxDHYLVAtQ0dbRQAIQN7R3CbGNC49zcBLz9YuDSy80swKNK403doxOrfOAB6XrhGD3FxYCgGeHFLAFscvVqM1UW1LAh6FzgPZnwhYHICGhA6JlYBYRIACgBKchJDZdUtneFcDBQcAh1dYnwdXJJLlc%20gNQO94GNLFA1E9dq9MB9fihvnNdADrsC4BAANZAA)

in your code TypeA extends TypeB but TypeB doesn't extends TypeA, that is why you don't get the error when compare TypeA to TypeB, but you will get error if you compare TypeB to TypeA