# How does the extends type definition with an arrow function with generics work?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to figure out how the **extends** statement to both sides works, I've seen this strategy somewhere else where there's use of an arrow function with an `infer` statement, but I can't wrap my mind around it.

```
type MyEqual<X, Y> = (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends <T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2 
  ? true 
  : false;
```

How does this work?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCiBHArgQwDYB4AaAaKAmgHxQC8UAFJgCpEUCUZJ1UEAHsBAHYAmAzlGxQA-FACMUAFxQATI3adeAmnUalmrDt36ER4qbKgAoKHuAAnZNBMGAZhj4QA3EaNA)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test if two types are exactly the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807517/how-to-test-if-two-types-are-exactly-the-same)

Comment: @TobiasS. not really, it just mentions implementation specifics of the`Equal` operator, but it doesn't explain the inner workings of the conditional strategy type used here

Comment: In this thread https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024 are also some explanations

Comment: Ok, yeah thank you. The most useful to me seems to be this one https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024#issuecomment-510924206 although it still looks like an obscure behavior.