# Typescript: ***Compile-time*** validation that two types are equal?

Tags: typescript

I'm looking to have the equivalent of C `static_assert()`, but only usable against compile-time data, such as type information (which isn't emitted).

I'd like something similar to the following...

```js
type TStrLit_0 = 'a' | 'b' | 'C' | 'd';
type TStrLit_1 = 'a' | 'b' | 'C' | 'd';
type TStrLit_2 = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd';
type TStrLit_3 = 'a' | 'b' | 'C'      ;
type TStrLit_4 = 'a' | 'b' | 'C' |'d' | 'e';

static_assert(  TypesAreEqual<TStrLit_0, TStrLit_1>() );
static_assert( !TypesAreEqual<TStrLit_0, TStrLit_2>() );
static_assert( !TypesAreEqual<TStrLit_0, TStrLit_3>() );
static_assert( !TypesAreEqual<TStrLit_0, TStrLit_4>() );

type TObject_0 = { a: number, b: string };
type TObject_1 = { a: number, b: string };
type TObject_2 = { a: number, b: number };
type TObject_3 = { a: number, B: string };
type TObject_4 = { a: number            };
type TObject_5 = { a: number, b: string, c: number };
type TObject_6 = { a: any,    b: any    };
static_assert( TypesAreEqual<TObject_0, TObject_1>() );
static_assert(!TypesAreEqual<TObject_0, TObject_2>() );
static_assert(!TypesAreEqual<TObject_0, TObject_3>() );
static_assert(!TypesAreEqual<TObject_0, TObject_4>() );
static_assert(!TypesAreEqual<TObject_0, TObject_5>() );
static_assert(!TypesAreEqual<TObject_0, TObject_6>() );
```

What I'm looking for is the generic ability to have typescript-specific, compile-time-only assertions based on the type information.

The compiler already generates the type information, but it's not emitted and thus any runtime assertions have to first change the source to emit extra metadata.

(e.g., for string literals, generating the type from an `as const` string array, adding typeguard functions, out-of-band tracking the relationship between those string literal types and the source string arrays, ... ugh!)

Having compile-time type information assertions would allow embedding assumed invariants into the code, saving future maintainers pain when they unknowingly violate those invariants.

***Does anything like this already exist?***

***Would this require changes to the TypeScript core, or can it be done with existing functionality?***

Thanks!

Comment: You will never pass a type as a value as at runtime, but purely in type land you can do something like https://tsplay.dev/Nrnl0N. Still not sure I understand _why_ though. I have a hunch you don't really need to do this. Perhaps if you explained more about the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Your `TStrLit_*` type definitions are not valid typescript. Do you want them to be tuples?  Or what?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807517/how-to-test-if-two-types-are-exactly-the-same

Comment: @jcalz ... string literal unions ... fixed ... thanks!

Comment: @AlexWayne -- The problem being solved is the addition of compile-time validation that expected invariants continue to hold. Examples:
* In larger projects, assumed invariants by one developer may later be accidentally invalidated.
* Avoiding the need to emit string literals into `const xVal : string[] = {} as const` arrays, for subsets of validation
* Foundation for more complex compile-time assertions.  <grin/>

Comment: Would something like the [types-plus](https://github.com/unional/type-plus) module work? In particular: standalone statements like `testType.equal<TObject_0, TObject_1>(true)` and also `testType.equal<TObject_0, TObject_2>(false)`

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the links in early comments(*), I came up with the following:

```js
type TypesAreEqual2<T, U> = [T] extends [U] ? [U] extends [T] ? true : false : false;
```

This appears to work for all the (admittedly simple) test cases I could come up with in 20 minutes:

See https://tsplay.dev/wRGDnN

(*) majusebetter pointed to a similar question that jcalz answered in 2018.  Alex Wayne provided a tsplayground link.  Neither of those solutions was exactly what I was looking for, but both were helpful in getting me the results I was looking for.  Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 1):

Visitors to this questions (like me) are potentially more interested in how to achieve an implementation of `static_assert` that generates no runtime code in the compiled output. OP's answer to their own question is focusing more on a `TypesAreEqual` implementation, though. In their tsplay.dev link the solution to the former does exist, however! The trick is to use [TypeScript generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints).
Below is the version I use in my project:

```
// definition
type static_assert<T extends true> = never;
// usage - does not hold true if reversed
type _check = static_assert<[] extends {} ? true : false>;
```