# Both function types have the same argument and return type, but `false` is returned by `extends` in TypeScript, why?

Tags: typescript

```
type ArgIsUnknown = <G>() => G extends unknown ? 1 : 2;
const fn: ArgIsUnknown = () => 1; // OK
type ArgIsAny = <G>() => G extends any ? 1 : 2;
const fn2: ArgIsAny = () => 1; // OK

type Result = ArgIsUnknown extends ArgIsAny ? true : false; // false
```

The conditional expression of ArgIsUnknown extends ArgIsAny returns false, why is this?

Comment: This is actually used to see if two types are exactly the same. You may find [the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807517/how-to-test-if-two-types-are-exactly-the-same) useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test if two types are exactly the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807517/how-to-test-if-two-types-are-exactly-the-same)