# Typescript function signature parameters required

Tags: typescript

I have the following type definition:

```js
type FuncWithRequiredParams = (a: number, b: number, c:string) => void

const func1: FuncWithRequiredParams = (a: number, b: number, c: string) => {} // works
const func2: FuncWithRequiredParams = (a: number, b: number, c: string, d: boolean) => {} // Error
const func3: FuncWithRequiredParams = (a: number, b: number) => {} // works, but I want to force it to fail
```

is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Why do you want to force it to error? There's nothing more annoying than having to type out parameters you'll never ever use in the function.

Comment: Is this [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Every day I develop more disdain for TypeScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's be clear that this behavior is in fact correct. In this code:

```
type FuncWithRequiredParams = (a: number, b: number, c: string) => void;
const func3: FuncWithRequiredParams = (a: number, b: number) => {};
```

the conversation between you and the compiler looks like this:

> TSC: Give me a function that I can call with three arguments.
>
> You: Here's a function with two parameters.
>
> TSC: Ok, I can call that with three arguments, your function will just ignore the third one. I'll take it.

And as [caTS points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74143054/typescript-function-signature-parameters-required#comment130905046_74143054), usually that's what you want. If a function doesn't even use its third parameter, why type it in the first place?

Now, I assume you have a good reason for wanting this (maybe there's a callback that every implementing function has to always call, or something like that), and it's more about making implementers aware of accidental mistakes.

Here's one solution that might work for you. I imagine your callbacks are going to be passed to some function like `registerPlugin` or `addMiddleware` or something along those lines.

If you make that function generic, have the compiler infer the exact type of the callback being passed in, and ensure that the inferred type matches the expected one *exactly*, you have at least *some* assurance:

```
type FuncWithRequiredParams = (a: number, b: number, c: string) => void;

const func1 = (a: number, b: number, c: string) => {};
const func2 = (a: number, b: number, c: string, d: boolean) => {};
const func3 = (a: number, b: number) => {};

type Identical<A, B> = A extends B ? (B extends A ? A : never) : never;

function registerPlugin<T>(f: Identical<T, FuncWithRequiredParams>) {
  // ...
}

registerPlugin(func1); // works
registerPlugin(func2); // error
registerPlugin(func3); // error
```

([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMYHUCWwAWAlCBHONAJwgBMAFAQyMoFsBnKAXigApKAuKBOWgIwhEANFD5ce-QSKRd6wImgQBzAJTMAfFABuAezSkA3ACgjSHQjlQAZoiQBGZm07deA4aPGupUGVDkLlNSZNAG8AX2MzC2BrWwAmR3ZPSXcxFxTpWXlFJRFSLj4dHQAbCEoEINCI03NLG2QAZkTnCTcRNNbBSqhw4yNQSCgASVIIBGA0JEpigB4AQREAIU0WOagIAA9gMdJGRagAfjZ9ze2EXag1o7XxCC0uqFv7oj76pAnzKBIlNDlBcmKcB+CBmABV1KwrFwRmMJlNZqCRPBkOgsLgCMQyFQaAx1GoQkYoFAAPTEqAAOkpRjCJm+v22RABQMUkNsdhUBhJZIA7joiABrehGOl-RmA4Gs5BxDlc9ZEIh84UQH6ipkSt4NGWkuUKohGIA))

Just be aware that this is is anything but foolproof (and it can't be, because as I pointed out earlier, the original behavior is technically just fine).

For example, if you explicitly provide the type parameter, the compiler won't complain:

```
registerPlugin<FuncWithRequiredParams>(func3); // works
```

And if you explicitly set the type of `func3` like you did in your original code:

```
const func3: FuncWithRequiredParams = (a: number, b: number) => {};

registerPlugin(func3); // works
```

it compiles as well.

Comment: ooo I think we should use `Equals` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807517/how-to-test-if-two-types-are-exactly-the-same) just to be safe. This "double" extends *kinda* works, but to cover all edge cases you need to do something really weird (see linked post).

Comment: Interesting read! I'm definitely going to try understanding that solution. Nonetheless, I would argue that it's rather futile to go any further. If you need something stricter than assignability, then a caller can always (completely legally, and not even deliberately) change the compile time type to be exactly what's being asked for, like in the two examples at the end of my post. In the end, all of this is not much more than sternly worded documentation that can help catch some mistakes, but doesn't provide any additional type safety.