# How to enforce type compliance on callback parameters

Tags: typescript

How would one get `foobar(fn)` below to error as property `b` is missing from the `arg` parameter type of `bar`?

```js
const foo = (arg: {a: any,b: any})=>1

const foobar = <T extends typeof foo>(arg:T)=>1

const bar = (arg: {a: string})=>1

// how would one type this so that `bar` is 
// flagged as invalid, because prop `b` is missing?
foobar(bar)
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=102&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MAUBDATgcwFwwDeGBGYAngDQBGpFAvgJTIB8AjAFAcIhrF5sADExgB6UTGrwANhhw4ApgBMYGCDAC2ASwgQtYHKvUKAHgAcFwKMq6hIsathQwAPABUYp62CXr+qiho6cnoWTFw8N2Z2LkcsPhIhETEJKThZeWUjTR09A2zTCysbDjtoeEQ453dPE29fGChyCxA4CpAw7Hwo1k4eOLQeRltwcrgwZ3D8IhIYaCx9HCZern7sQbBGGBSYAAsQAHcYA5AAV2kVcAVG5uuoXZ05pHuMWHGYR-S5RRU1D7AAG4YaRaJSUSSWDCnCDXMxYEBmGAAA2oSI+6m0ukWAH4gA)

To my human brain `bar` doesn't extend `foo` - I believe this is happening due to contravariance but I'm still ignorant, hence the question.

Comment: Why though? This is like making TypeScript throw an error if a function is ignoring a parameter (by excluding it from the signature).

Comment: Which is the question: are you trying to force an error, or understand why there isn't one? What, specifically, is wrong with `foobar(bar)` that makes you want an error there? The `any` is really making this extra confused, because it turns off type checking. And `foobar` is unnecessarily generic; the type `<T extends U>(x: T)=>number` is essentially the same as `(x: U)=>number`, so why use the former instead of the latter? Do you mind if I reduce the example code to [this](//tsplay.dev/mAr6kW), which has the same important features of the question? Then I can tell you why TS allows it.

Comment: Anyway, let me know.  Getting TS to emit an error where there isn't a type safety hazard is possible, but seems like an XY problem, especially since the thing you presumably *want* to allow [is actually dangerous](https://tsplay.dev/m36DbN). I think the "right" approach here is to [explain contravariance](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance). If you agree that the example code I present captures the same issue and want me to write up an answer explaining, please mention @jcalz in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Extremely useful type that we'll need (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807517/how-to-test-if-two-types-are-exactly-the-same)):

```
type Equals<T, U> =
  (<G>() => G extends T ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<G>() => G extends U ? 1 : 2) ? true : false;
```

Then you can just check if `T` is equal to the type of `foo`:

```
const foobar = <T extends typeof foo>(arg: Equals<T, typeof foo> extends true ? T : never)=>1
```

and if it is, it should be `T`, otherwise `never`.

Seems to work!

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NB5rDw)

Comment: Thank you for this solution - most useful. I'm also after a solution that works with extends - i.e. `{a: string,b: string}` extends `{a: any,b: any}` and so should be valid, even though it is not strictly equal. [code](https://tsplay.dev/mbQD8N) that shows what I mean.