# is there a way to type compare methods of 2 typescript modules?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, continuous-integration, automated-tests, github-actions

examples:

`api.ts`

```js
export const getStuffs = async (term:string): Promise<Stuff[]> => {
   const stuffs = await getStuffsFromDB(term);
   return stuffs;
}
```

`mock_api.ts`

```js
export const getStuffs = async (term:string): Promise<Stuff[]> => {
   const stuffs = [
     { ... hardcoded stuff }
   ];
   return stuffs;
}
```

is there a way to add in a CI/CD test to compare that the two provided example module above are equal in type input/output: `(term:string):Promise<stuff[]>` ?

The objective is to automatically remind devs to always replicate the exported methods in `api.ts` to be mocked in `mock_api.ts`

Answer (score 0):

Using the two generic helper types [`IfEquals`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807517/how-to-test-if-two-types-are-exactly-the-same) and `BeTrue`, we can check at compile time if two types are equal.

```
type IfEquals<T, U> =
  (<G>() => G extends T ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<G>() => G extends U ? 1 : 2) ? true : false;

type BeTrue<T extends true> = T
```

Import both functions into a single file but be sure two give one of them an alias to avoid the naming collision.

You can now check the two function types for equality.

```
declare let res: BeTrue<IfEquals<typeof getStuffs, typeof getStuffs2>>
```

This line will emit a compile time error if the types are not equal.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIGVQFcBmLYF5YGdQCcBLAOwHMRoAPSAez1FgGNqjdYTpRFUVtNYBDbOCINYAClDQ8AWwBcuQqQCUs2AAU81aQWzQAPFzQBtALoA+TBYDewWHaYt6ubryz8A7vwL12nZGmwAMU1pABEAIQkpaSUAbls7PA4kPCIcfx54gF9yKlp6B1ZfQx4AJj5BYVEomXl8YhIVdRCdfRLTCwxrBMZmVmcAviMeuytYADpJ2AALfjwAEyZ56Hn07lgcu1gTeK2k5FS1gOyQMCg4AEkUAFEARyR+ABtsPQAVABpYAFVOhLE9ADiZjESkssABsEokiI814r1gAH5YABGWCqUqgqHQGHYP6A4GgrrgyEUaGw76IlFo2AYyn4JBwVQoJ66eJnGCwcLQV54BlvElk3j06CdWCvEDLBiPOZwR4cWBJbCqLk8vlXO4PZ56CAwajoYoZbCfHXQPVsDglbClMxmIA)

---

```
import * as api from './api.ts'
import * as mockApi from './mock-api.ts'

for(let k in api) {  
  let key = k as keyof typeof api
  declare let res: BeTrue<IfEqual<typeof api[key], typeof mockApi[key]>>
}
```

Comment: this sort-of works but i would be required to declare and import each method in a static way. Is it possible for  something like this:

```typescript
for(let key of api) {
  declare let res: BeTrue<IfEqual> typeof api[key], typeof mockApi[key]>
}
```

Comment: @NeilMolina What is `api` and `mockApi`? An array of methods?

Comment: @MikeS. its a module thing of this way
`import * as api from './api.ts'`

Answer (score 0):

> The objective is to automatically remind devs to always replicate the exported methods in api.ts to be mocked in mock_api.ts

You don't really need CI/CD to check this for you, instead you could simply create a interface that defines the methods you need:

```
interface ApiMethods {
    getStuffs: (term: string) => Promise<any[]>
}
```

Then create an object in each of your files that implement this interface:

```
const apiMethods: ApiMethods = {
    getStuffs: async () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {resolve([])});
    }
}

const mockMethods: ApiMethods = {
    getStuffs: async () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {resolve([])});
    }
}
```

Adding a new method/property to `ApiMethods` will now force you to implement those in `apiMethods` and `mockMethods`.

Comment: thanks. i think it will work but id prefer not to require devs to create an object of methods