# Generic arrow functions in conditional types

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

While working through the typescript challenges I bumped into the following snippet (simplified):

```js
type MyEqual<X, Y> = (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends <T>() => T extends Y
  ? 1
  : 2
  ? true
  : false;
```

This can be used like this:

```js
type test1 = MyEqual<{ bar: number }, { readonly bar: number }>
//   ^? false

type test2 = MyEqual<{ bar: number }, { bar: number }>
//   ^? true
```

Problem is I'm struggling to understand what `<T>` does in `MyEqual`, how does it get its value and generally how it works.

Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: There are no [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) in this question.  Perhaps you mean [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html)?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I tried to simplify my question but apparently backfired. I was trying to figure out https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/issues/5221#issue-1082962800 which is the solution to this typescript challenge: https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/main/questions/05181-hard-mutable-keys/README.md. I still don't understand what `T` is though... I'd love an answer version!

Comment: But can you [edit] to change "mapped types" to "conditional types"?  I'm working on an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually not particularly illuminating to understand what `T` is doing in `<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2`.  Let's forget about that for now and come back to it later.

---

You're looking at a particular implementation of the so-called *type-level equality operator*, as discussed in [How to test if two types are exactly the same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53807517/2887218).  There are types in TypeScript which are *mutually assignable* (that is, you can assign a value of type `X` to a variable of type `Y` and vice versa) but which are represented differently by the compiler.  For example, the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `{a: 0} & {b: 1}` is mutually assignable to the single object type `{a: 0; b: 1}`, but they are not considered "identical" according to the compiler.  The goal of `MyEqual<X, Y>` is to somehow get the compiler to tell you whether it considers `X` and `Y` to be identical and not just mutually assignable.

Most naive implementations would give you the latter, like this:

```
type MyEqual<X, Y> = [X] extends [Y] ? [Y] extends [X] ? true : false : false
```

---

One approach you could take is to find a "[black box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box)" type function which is so complicated that the compiler has no idea how to analyze what it does.  We don't really care what it does either, just that the compiler can't do any analysis on it.  So we're looking for a type function like

```
type BlackBox<Z> = ⋯Z⋯ // something goes here
```

that's so complicated that the compiler only thinks `BlackBox<X> extends BlackBox<Y>` if `X` and `Y` are completely identical.  If they're not identical then the compiler just gives up and says that `BlackBox<X>` and `BlackBox<Y>` are different.

Then you could almost write `MyEqual` like

```
type MyEqual<X, Y> = BlackBox<X> extends BlackBox<Y> ? true : false;
```

...except that the compiler will take a shortcut since both are referring to the same `BlackBox` definition.  So the approach will have to be to either *inline* `BlackBox` into `MyEqual` like

```
type MyEqual<X, Y> = ⋯X⋯ extends ⋯Y⋯ ? true : false;
// where ⋯X⋯ is what you get if you copy `BlackBox<X>` 
// definition in manually
```

or define two syntactically identical `BlackBox` type functions.  That is, we can write

```
type BlackBox1<Z> = ⋯Z⋯
type BlackBox2<Z> = ⋯Z⋯ // <-- identical to the above except for the name
type MyEqual<X, Y> = BlackBox1<X> extends BlackBox2<Y> ? true : false;
```

---

So now the goal is to look for an appropriate `BlackBox<Z>` definition.    It turns out that the following one works:

```
type BlackBox<Z> = <T>() => T extends Z ? 1 : 2
```

and therefore you could write

```
type BlackBoxA<Z> = <T>() => T extends Z ? 1 : 2
type BlackBoxB<Z> = <T>() => T extends z ? 1 : 2
type MyEqual<X, Y> = BlackBoxA<X> extends BlackBoxB<Y> ? true : false;
```

or the equivalent

```
type MyEqual<X, Y> = (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends 
  (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? true : false;
```

---

Again, we really don't care what `BlackBox<Z>` does to `Z` or what type it represents.  It's not important for our purposes.  We really only need it to be a "black box".  Still, you seem to want to know, so let's look at it.  But don't be surprised if it makes no sense or seems to serve no purpose.  It's because to some extent it *does* make no sense and *doesn't* serve a purpose.

Okay, so given:

```
type BlackBox<Z> = <T>() => T extends Z ? 1 : 2
```

what do we get if we plug in something for `Z`.  Say, `string`?  then we get

```
type BlackBoxString = <T>() => T extends string ? 1 : 2
```

That's a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function type which takes one *type* argument `T` and *no* function arguments, and returns a value of the [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) `T extends string ? 1 : 2`. As written, `T` isn't currently doing anything, because in generic functions, type parameters stay unresolved until such time as you *call* the function.  So `T` won't be anything until we have a function of this type and call it.

Let's see what should happen if we had a function of this type and called it:

```
declare const bbs: BlackBoxString;

const t = bbs(); // T cannot be inferred, becomes unknown
// const t: 2;
const u = bbs<string>();
// const u: 1;
const v = bbs<number>();
// const v: 2;
const w = bbs<"abc">();
// const w: 1;
const x = bbs<string | number>();
// const x: 1 | 2;
```

So when you call `bbs()` and don't manually specify its type argument, type inference completely fails (there's nowhere for `T` to be inferred), and it falls back to `unknown`.  So `bbs()` produces a value of type `unknown extends string ? 1 : 2` which is `2` because `unknown` does not extend `string`.  If you manually specify the type arguments you get either `1` or `2` or `1 | 2` out of the function depending on whether or not the type argument is `string`-ish.

This is a useless function type.  Nobody would ever want a function of this type.  It doesn't do anything good for anyone.  And it's lucky that nobody wants a function like this, since *it's completely impossible to actually implement a function of this type*.  At runtime there is no `T`, and so `bbs` would have to somehow know whether to output `1` or `2` based on information it doesn't have.

So `BlackBox<Z>` represents a completely useless and almost always unimplementable generic function type.  But again, we don't really care what it does.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAhATgewNYWAeQFcAXJAbwChylqkiBPGZFAGwSxQwA8BBAHgC0AfEgC8SXgBVBACgCUo4RKQRORXABMoSfkgD8SAIxIAXEgBMVGvUapW8dlxQDhYyTPkjFy1Rq079RqYWNLQMyACydACiAI4EIMy8ABoANEgAmi62bBw8ycIqasCa2fa5Tpl6tGgEyKYAZglQEADclCHWyGpQREZikbHxiaRIAEYgaKbABGCjEGhIAL5pI2gQIOoYwMx0YxNTM3MLi4KW1AD05zQAevqNzM3tVmG00ERmokgDcQm8I+OTJDTWbzJYrPaA4FHJanEKXG76Ig1CCUciLSigSCwBDIACS2wAlsBkBQzqEbN8hsk0pUxNI3HIFEglIVfEgklVAuZ5KzilAySF6VJGZ5md4iiV0pyTNyqkjajL7s02mTOq8en0vtEfsMIQcQcdwWsNlsdnqgYdQScyfDqLckEqUaqXt13p9Kb9-vsLQawWRzVCrbCaLakPb5U70eRMdA4IgkFFODBmBg1mRnTYWDkuM5PgyPF5eSV-IYZcFnpm7A5OABlJFEgDmnyzZRzPTQjcEbRC6gg8FYafgWx6Y1GUFMLerdY7wAbKpCQ+AI5IYlGY7kLSQ8KU8BAwGAGBIcyQRPq8zW6jScyHWKQBGAWAPAHdgDarovl0FuzQPyQCJ81ygXh207Dc3yQX871MAxv2oSCADcALHXhAzQdxYK3d9hxIeCvzJSCnyQoCACIQFGeBiPQ8CCOgjDIM4IjgPrWckAAHx9I4qLhLClxIThoLY8w2kWIA)

Comment: WoW! That's one of the best and most informative responses I've had in years! Thank you so much @jcalz! And kudos for going the extra mile to explain what `BlackBox<Z>` truly means here. There's just one minor thing I didn't really get: At some point you talk about this: "...except that the compiler will take a shortcut since both are referring to the same BlackBox definition" and you suggest inlining or creating 2 syntactically identical type functions. Why is that? What kind of shortcut does the compiler take that messes this whole thing up?

Comment: I didn't want to digress any further, but basically if you compare `Foo<X>` to `Foo<Y>` with the same `Foo`, the compiler will almost always first compare `X` and `Y` directly to save time, but that's exactly not what we want.  (If you could just ask the compiler to compare `X` and `Y` in the way we wanted, we wouldn't have bothered with `BlackBox` at all).

Comment: ...so you are suggesting that in that case the default comparison is "assignability based" and not the "identical" thing we're looking for here, right?

Comment: Yeah pretty much... I don't have all the details; you'd have to step thru the compiler code to be sure what exactly it's using, but it's certainly not using the "identical" check

Answer (score 0):

The `'<T>()=> ...`' syntax in TypeScript defines a generic function that takes no arguments and returns a value. In the '`MyEqual`' type, this syntax is used to check if one type extends another. '' is a type parameter that is inferred based on the context in which it is used. If the two functions return the same value, 'My Equal' evaluates to '`true`', otherwise it evaluates to '`false`'.

Read more about generic functions [here](https://www.scaler.com/topics/typescript/generic-functions-in-typescript/)

Comment: "If the two functions return the same value, 'My Equal' evaluates to 'true', otherwise it evaluates to 'false'" This is either incorrect or not expressed clearly enough to be verifiably true.  The two function types would quite probably return the same value without `MyEqual` being `true`.  Can you elaborate?