# Extract all mismatched keys from two types

Tags: typescript, types

I have two translation `.json` files that are huge, and I'm looking for a way to raise an error when some keys are missing on each or some keys are different.

Take the following examples:

```
// a.json
{
  "a": "hello",
  "b": {},
  "c": {}
}

// b.json
{
  "a": "ciao",
  "c": {
    "d": "mondo"
  }
}
```

I would like to correctly raise an error on the `b` key since it is missing in the `b.json` file and on the key `c` since they are not the same.

This is like set difference so I wrote the following:

```
type A = {
  a: string;
  b: {
    c: string;
  };
  c: string;
};

type B = {
  a: string;
  c: {};
};

type Prettify<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] } & {};

type Difference<T, U> = {
  [K in keyof T as K extends keyof U
    ? T[K] extends U[K]
      ? never
      : K
    : K]: T[K];
};

type MismatchedKeys = Prettify<Difference<A, B> & Difference<B, A>>;
```

But I can't find a way to make it recursive.

### Edit

The `MismatchedKeys` in this example is

```
type MismatchedKeys = {
    b: {
        c: string;
    };
    c: {};
}
```

However I need just the keys since I would like to build a [custom error](https://media-codings.com/articles/throwing-custom-compile-time-errors-with-typescript) when needed

Comment: What type, *specifically*, should `MismatchedKeys` be for this example?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `{ b: { c: string }, c: {} | string }`. But I don't need the key's values. I just need to keys

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nr8eVW) meet your needs?  These sorts of deeply nested types tend to have bizarre edge cases, so please test against use cases you care about.  If it works for you I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yup, it works. Please write your answer, I will gladly accept it

Comment: That was quick; I am a bit worried that I'll write up an answer and then you'll say "oh actually this almost works except for this one little thing" and that will make me need to completely refactor the type.  Have you thoroughly checked against your expected range of use cases?

Comment: @jcalz yeah it works. I'll just need to add a custom compiler error when the object is not empty but I will take care of it by myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat for possible future readers: these nested recursive type manipulations tend to have bizarre edge cases (e.g., what happens with union types, index signatures, optional properties, etc) and often fixing them requires a refactoring of the entire type.  The solution I present below works for the example from the question and is apparently sufficient for the person who asked the question, but you might have a different use case where it does something you don't like.  It is therefore important that people test such types thoroughly against their expected range of use cases, and be prepared to rewrite things.

---

Okay, here's one possible approach to implementing `SymmetricDiff<T, U>` which resolves to the "difference" between `T` and `U`, for some definition of "difference":

```
type SymmetricDiff<T, U> =
  [T, U] extends [object, object] ? (
    { [K in keyof T | keyof U as KeyIfDiff<K, T, U>]:
      K extends keyof T ? K extends keyof U ?
      SymmetricDiff<T[K], U[K]> : T[K] : U[Extract<K, keyof U>] }) :
  T | U

type KeyIfDiff<K extends PropertyKey, T, U> =
  K extends keyof T ? K extends keyof U ? T[K] extends U[K] ?
  U[K] extends T[K] ? never : K : K : K : K;
```

The idea is that if either `T` or `U` are not object types, then we can just return the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `T | U`, since we know they are different and we don't need to iterate over the properties.  Otherwise, if both `T` and `U` are object types, then we [map](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over all the keys from `T` and all the keys from `U`.

When we do that, first we use [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) in `KeyIfDiff<K, T, U>` to suppress any keys `K` where `T[K]` and `U[K]` both exist and are mutually assignable to each other (`T[K] extends U[K]` and `U[K] extends T[K]]`).  This is the criterion I'm using to determine types that have no difference; if you don't want to use that because it's not strict enough, you will need to come up with your own idea of what "the same" means; perhaps using the technique from [How to test if two types are exactly the same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53807517/2887218). So in what follows then, we only will have keys `K` where there is some difference between `T` and `U` at that key.

If `K` exists both in the keys of `T` and the keys of `U`, here is where we want to recursively evaluate `SymmetricDiff<T[K], U[K]>`.  Otherwise we will evaluate either `T[K]` or `U[K]`, whichever one exists.  (In the implementation the compiler isn't smart enough to understand that `K` must exist as a key of at least one of `T` or `U`, so I have to use `Extract<K, keyof U>` via [the `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to convince the compiler to let me index `U` with `K`.

---

Okay, let's test it out:

```
type A = {
  a: string;
  b: {
    c: string;
  };
  c: string;
};

type B = {
  a: string;
  c: {};
};

type MismatchedKeys = SymmetricDiff<A, B>;
/* type MismatchedKeys = {
    b: {
        c: string;
    };
    c: string | {};
} */
```

Looks good, the `MismatchedKeys` doesn't have `a` because both `A` and `B` have identical `a` properties.  It does have `b` from `A` because only `A` has a `b` property.  And for `c` it has the union of the property from `A` and `B` because they are different from each other.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#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)