# Why is this type function extending to T / U and returning 1 or 2?

Tags: typescript, conditional-statements, extends

```
type IsEqual<T, U> =
    (<G>() => G extends T ? 1 : 2) extends
    (<G>() => G extends U ? 1 : 2)
        ? true
        : false;
```

There are a few things that confuse me about this function:

1. I'm trying to understand why this function is returning a 1 and a 2. What is the reason?
2. What is the type variable G doing? Is the purpose to just create a function template?
3. What other way is there to implement this same type function? Is this method the most optimized  or up to date way for this approach?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test if two types are exactly the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807517/how-to-test-if-two-types-are-exactly-the-same)

Comment: This is pretty explicitly three questions in one post; please [edit] the question to have a single well-defined question.  Also you should probably mention where you got this code from and what it said its purpose was, so that people who want to answer don't have to guess.

Comment: I am mostly confused about the return of 1 and 2. I have already read the link posted above and another link that leads to a github page further explaining it. But I can't find where they explain the reason for returning 1 and 2.

Comment: I'd love to help but I've asked for a few things to be done in my previous comment, and I'm not inclined to engage further unless they happen.  Good luck!