# Map from object type to function params in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

At the end of this post I have functioning code for mapping from object types to a function that takes an object with matching properties. The code I attached resolves 'result' into:

```
type result = {
    GENERATION_COMPLETE: (params: {
        generation: ImageGeneration;
    }) => void;
    IMAGE_VOTE: (params: {
        voteForId: string;
    }) => void;
    SCORE_SCREEN_DONE: () => void;
    SUBMIT_THEME: (params: {
        theme: string;
    }) => void;
    THEME_VOTE: (params: {
        voteForId: string;
    }) => void;
}
```

However, I want to map directly to function params, not an object with properties as a function parameter. Such that the result would expand to this instead:

```
type result = {
    GENERATION_COMPLETE: (
        generation: ImageGeneration;
    ) => void;
    IMAGE_VOTE: (
        voteForId: string;
    ) => void;
    SCORE_SCREEN_DONE: () => void;
    SUBMIT_THEME: (
        theme: string;
    ) => void;
    THEME_VOTE: (
        voteForId: string;
    ) => void;
}
```

Type code:

```
type DreamEventSchema =
    | { type: 'GENERATION_COMPLETE', generation: ImageGeneration }
    | { type: 'IMAGE_VOTE', voteForId: string }
    | { type: 'SCORE_SCREEN_DONE' }
    | { type: 'SUBMIT_THEME', theme: string }
    | { type: 'THEME_VOTE', voteForId: string }

type OmitType<T> = Omit<T, 'type'> extends infer Omitted ? { [K in keyof Omitted]: Omitted[K] } : never;
type IsEmptyType<T> = keyof T extends never ? true : false;
type EventToFunction<Events extends { type: string }> = {
    [E in Events as E['type']]: (
        OmitType<E> extends infer Omitted
        ? IsEmptyType<Omitted> extends true
            ? () => void 
            : (params: Omitted) => void 
        : never
    )
}
type result = EventToFunction<DreamEventSchema>;
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: What if `params` has more than one property? How would anything know the order of the properties?

Comment: @jcalz I saw a github thread from a few years ago discussing a typescript feature request for what I am asking to do now, and it got shot down for the reason that property declaration order cannot be relied on. I don't really understand why this is an issue, could you elaborate? For my use case the order of declaration seems fine, but perhaps this falls apart in other more advanced use cases?

Comment: TypeScript cannot distinguish the types `{a: A, b: B}` and `{b: B, a: A}`. They are the same type. Furthermore, `keyof` on those will produce either `"a" | "b"` or `"b" | "a"`, and it's not necessarily true that the order displayed for those union elements has anything to do with the order of the keys in the type.  So TS cannot consistently turn `{type: 'X', a: A, b: B}` turn into `{X: (a: A, b: B) => void}` as opposed to `{X: (b: B, a: A) => void}`. Unless you have just one property, I'm not sure how it "seems fine" for your use case. Could you demonstrate?

Answer (score 0):

By modifying your input schema type so that the labelled function parameter(s) are [labelled elements of a tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements) at a fixed property (e.g. `params`)…

```ts
type ImageGeneration = unknown;

type DreamEventSchema =
    | { type: "GENERATION_COMPLETE"; params: [generation: ImageGeneration] }
    | { type: "IMAGE_VOTE"; params: [voteForId: string] }
    | { type: "SCORE_SCREEN_DONE"; params: [] }
    | { type: "SUBMIT_THEME"; params: [theme: string] }
    | { type: "THEME_VOTE"; params: [voteForId: string] };
```

…you can derive the expected type with a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) that simply picks those fields out of the union members:

```ts
type Transform<
  U extends Readonly<{ type: string; params: readonly unknown[] }>,
> = { [T in U as T["type"]]: (...params: T["params"]) => void };

type Expected = {
  GENERATION_COMPLETE: (generation: ImageGeneration) => void;
  IMAGE_VOTE: (voteForId: string) => void;
  SCORE_SCREEN_DONE: () => void;
  SUBMIT_THEME: (theme: string) => void;
  THEME_VOTE: (voteForId: string) => void;
};

type Actual = Transform<DreamEventSchema>;
/*   ^?
type Actual = {
  GENERATION_COMPLETE: (generation: unknown) => void;
  IMAGE_VOTE: (voteForId: string) => void;
  SCORE_SCREEN_DONE: () => void;
  SUBMIT_THEME: (theme: string) => void;
  THEME_VOTE: (voteForId: string) => void;
} */

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/53808212/438273
type Equal<A, B> =
  (<T>() => T extends A ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<T>() => T extends B ? 1 : 2) ? true : false;

declare const equal: Equal<Actual, Expected>;
            //^? const equal: true
```

[Code in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#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-GEkeasdpwqWTolHburQIdgteDIdBYPB9ZjYIYjCYqhDWQpQe8AegfAD0APxFJ9QSbAYBgZRPkQEHGXQMGGOA0HYIwonGDBsAfBAHwAVgAZgADgABlQgAmABGLCHwAFjQrCAHZkK6SAoAGABHHd2FwHZbCgYVHCcIgIlwGBrAiVsPAoKhaHoHYoFfKAcKgIQsIyfjqDodjOO43iyEoWT6GFESxIkqApI00QtGgIQ0F3FAIE6GgIHGdgFGgGDUGAMhaN3IQaLohjt13JiXTdD1b3we9-IC-ynzffAgA)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot alter the form of the input tuple, because it is being used by a library

Comment: I could possibly map from your modified schema to what I had. Going to give it a try, and then decide if its worth the gymnastics. Thanks

Comment: Doesnt seem to be possible to map from labeled tuples to objects. Maybe there is something else that can map to objects and function parameters, but I do not know what that would be.

Comment: @GeraldLang AFAIK, labels are exclusively documentation artifacts in the type system, and as such cannot be either derived from or used to derive type information (e.g. string literals). Without altering your input type to include the parameter label information as actual labels, I don’t think it’ll be possible to have those in the transformed type.