# Type equality for partial update types

Tags: typescript, type-testing

Having a type Task:

```ts
type Task = {
  id: string;
  prop1: string;
  prop2: number;
}
```

I was trying to properly type an argument which will allow me to express an update to the task:

- id - required - to find appropriate tasks
- any number of props - optional - the updates to task props

I came up with two alternatives:

```ts
type TaskUpdate1 = Pick<Task, 'id'> & Partial<Omit<Task, 'id'>>;
type TaskUpdate2 = Pick<Task, 'id'> & Partial<Task>;
```

which, to my eyes, are the same, but two type assertion libraries claim they are different:

```ts
import { Expect, Equal } from 'type-testing';
import { assert, _ } from "spec.ts";

type Task = {
  id: string;
  prop1: string;
  prop2: number;
}

type TaskUpdate1 = Pick<Task, 'id'> & Partial<Omit<Task, 'id'>>;
type TaskUpdate2 = Pick<Task, 'id'> & Partial<Task>;

type test_0 = Expect<Equal<TaskUpdate1, TaskUpdate2>>;

var x = {} as TaskUpdate1;
var y = {} as TaskUpdate2;

assert(x, y);
```

Is there any difference in these types (and if so, what difference? To rephrase it: is there a value that belongs to one and not the other?), or is is a deficiency in the type testing code?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgUQB5gKYGMYBoUCOArgIYA2cAvnAGZQQhwDkMAnpgLQwYDOMwAOwDmTANwAoUJFiI4JHjwyx8AfSq16jAEQ9MWAHQweWieLaY4AFXkBrOAF5E4uHGAATAFxw%20UQUIkuYPRgAIxePn4BcEEQYABMXgJEIABGShKU4mbsGFa2AKpgbiTcIQ5wAArAWDYAPNY8NvhM7kwAfHAAZJUksMDktQDyIMAw9bbNrW1tEua5DTaFxdxx5VU1442Tbu1dPX0DCzNZc3DcfCoADOVoemPIxIcFRSUYIfgLS69x06YAbr04KhyghqPI8o0vqUJACoHBWCCwTwIYsXitTPJFLAABSofCsACUoiAA)

**Update**

The question obviously on knowledge of type-testing and spec.ts
I inlined types from these libraries to make the question more self-contained:

```ts
/* type-testing: https://github.com/MichiganTypeScript/type-testing/ */
export type Equal<A, B> =
  (<T>() => T extends A ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<T>() => T extends B ? 1 : 2)
  ? true
  : false;

export type Expect<T extends true> = Equal<T, true>;

/* spec.ts: https://github.com/aleclarson/spec.ts */
// Give "any" its own class
export class Any {
  private _: true = true;
}

type TestExact<Left, Right> =
  (<U>() => U extends Left ? 1 : 0) extends (<U>() => U extends Right ? 1 : 0) ? Any : never;

type IsAny<T> = Any extends T ? ([T] extends [Any] ? 1 : 0) : 0;

export type Test<Left, Right> = IsAny<Left> extends 1
  ? IsAny<Right> extends 1
    ? 1
    : "❌ Left type is 'any' but right type is not"
  : IsAny<Right> extends 1
  ? "❌ Right type is 'any' but left type is not"
  : [Left] extends [Right]
  ? [Right] extends [Left]
    ? Any extends TestExact<Left, Right>
      ? 1
      : "❌ Unexpected or missing 'readonly' property"
    : "❌ Right type is not assignable to left type"
  : "❌ Left type is not assignable to right type";

type Assert<T, U> = U extends 1
  ? T // No error.
  : IsAny<T> extends 1
  ? never // Ensure "any" is refused.
  : U; // Return the error message.

export const assert: <Left, Right>(
  left: Assert<Left, Test<Left, Right>>,
  right: Assert<Right, Test<Left, Right>>
) => Right = () => ({}) as any;

/* My code */

type Task = {
  id: string;
  prop1: string;
  prop2: number;
}

type TaskUpdate1 = Pick<Task, 'id'> & Partial<Omit<Task, 'id'>>;
type TaskUpdate2 = Pick<Task, 'id'> & Partial<Task>;

type test_0 = Expect<Equal<TaskUpdate1, TaskUpdate2>>;

var x = {} as TaskUpdate1;
var y = {} as TaskUpdate2;

assert(x, y);
```

Comment: Does this question depend on "type-testing" and "spec.ts" to answer?  If so then you might want to tag it as such or (if no tag is appropriate) make it obvious in the question that knowledge of these is required to answer.  If not then you might want to remove the apparent dependency on them.  Right now all I can say is that those two types are structurally identical (as evidenced by an identity mapped type shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WkzRJm)), but whatever you're using to check type equality is doing something *else*. Please let me know how you'd like to proceed.

Comment: @jcalz I think the main question has been answered - the types are identical. I inlined the definitions of these libraries to make the question self-contained. type-testing is only a couple of lines, and spec.ts seems to be based on your answer to 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807517/how-to-test-if-two-types-are-exactly-the-same My hope is to understand why the type assertions fail in my case.

Comment: The types are *structurally* identical, but that doesn't mean the compiler represents them identically internally, and depending on what check you're doing it might not treat them identically; indeed some of that other code is especially designed to try to figure out if the types are internally represented identically or different.  They are not tools you should use for testing structural equivalence.  Shall I write this up as an answer or am I missing something?

Comment: It seems I was having too high expectations - I expected these libs to test the types structurally, irrespective of how they were produced. In a lot of cases they do a pretty good job, I expected same here (given that the output type is quite straightforward). Please write up an answer if you have a spare moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two types are [structually](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) equivalent, meaning that for most practical purposes they should behave the same.

You can demonstrate the structural equivalence by writing an identity [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to walk through each property and give its resulting type (see [How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57683303/2887218) for similar ideas):

```
type Id<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] }

type TaskUpdate1 = Pick<Task, 'id'> & Partial<Omit<Task, 'id'>>;
type TU1 = Id<TaskUpdate1>;
/* type TU1 = {
    id: string;
    prop1?: string | undefined;
    prop2?: number | undefined;
}*/

type TaskUpdate2 = Pick<Task, 'id'> & Partial<Task>;
type TU2 = Id<TaskUpdate2>;
/* type TU2 = {
    id: string;
    prop1?: string | undefined;
    prop2?: number | undefined;
}*/
```

So even though `TaskUpdate1` and `TaskUpdate2` are represented differently, they produce identical `TU1` and `TU2` types.

---

As for why `Equal` and `assert` seem them as being different, it looks like those type equality operators were not intended to check for mere *structural* equivalence. Instead they are closer to checking that the types are actually represented in equivalent ways by the type checker.  That's what [How to test if two types are exactly the same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53807517/2887218) and its answers are about.  I'm not sure how someone using a type-level equality operators wants [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) like this to behave, and whether or not this would be considered a bug, a design limitation, or an intended feature of the libraries you're using.  But in any case I'd say they do not meet your needs and you shouldn't use them here.

Generally speaking I'd recommend just using mutual assignability (or [compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html)) as a metric for equality, like

```
declare let tu1: TaskUpdate1;
declare let tu2: TaskUpdate1;
tu1 = tu2; // okay
tu2 = tu1; // okay
```

until and unless you find a specific use case in which that is insufficient.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgZwNZQLxQN4CgpQJYAmAXFAsAE54B2A5gNw5RjkD2YAjCWZbQ7s2wBMJKgFcAtgCMI5BgF8sWUJCgBJAgB4YAPjSYoAbQDS+KlCQQQLAGawAuiRjG7UBUvDR4yAKpgCcYAh2PQAFPABjJC1EJAAaKAByQgTdADIoELhyYDw4ABsNAHlxPGBo5HikghTtBmVPb2D0dXKkX39A9lqsAHoAKih62Ea9bFxcQi4KanpGflYOAH4pnhooAB8oUSoCCGtqCAI+cYEwQWWoMSkZDa2dvYOjrDk+nsUhrza-AIhBUIiop9Ksk0hksjl8q1uh9vH9mppPu0foJuv1Bh5hnDMHN8MRSNNeDjTuwLtwZrdtrt9lRDsd5kILldpOQKfdqbTnq9FLtwnkstA8hBgINRJxYDEkZ0GDy+eQBUKRcJxT5vlKlKK9MBRII6FAej0oCwkHAQOqsVr2Lr9YbjSAgA)