# How to type vue instance out of `defineComponent()` in vue 3?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

As you know, as of Vue 3, component could be written in TypeScript:

```
/// modal.vue

<template>
  <div class="modal"></div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Modal",
  props: {
    foo: String,
    bar: String
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$props.foo // how to type `this` out of this context?
  }
});
</script>
```

My question is how can I type the vue instance out of the `defineComponent` function?

```
/// another ts file.
let modal:???; // what the `???` should be?

modal.$props.foo // infer `$props.foo` correctly
```

Answer (score 10):

Use the TypeScript's built-in `InstanceType` utility to extract its instance type

```js
import Modal from './modal.vue'

type ModalInstance = InstanceType<typeof Modal>

type Foo = ModalInstance['$props']['foo']
```

[image]

Another one using a utility type:

```
import { AllowedComponentProps, Component, defineComponent, VNodeProps } from 'vue'

export type ExtractComponentProps<TComponent> =
  TComponent extends new () => {
    $props: infer P;
  }
    ? Omit<P, keyof VNodeProps | keyof AllowedComponentProps>
    : never;
  
const TestComponent = defineComponent({
  props: {
    disabled: {
      type: Boolean,
    },
  },
});
  
type Props = ExtractComponentProps<typeof TestComponent>

// type Props = {
//   disabled?: boolean | undefined;
// }
```

Answer (score 9):

The "simple" answer I was going to give was to use `ReturnType<typeof defineComponent>` however that doesn't carry any of the type information.  As I started to look at how `ReturnType` could be used with a generic method I fell down [stackoverflow rabbit hole where these seemed like something to explore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52963637/typescript-is-it-possible-to-get-the-return-type-of-a-generic-function/60846777#60846777)

However after looking at it, vue has an exported type [`ComponentPublicInstance`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/6aeafef1a548fbe9ea970bb73178cba3608c0fa7/packages/runtime-core/src/componentPublicInstance.ts#L162) that can be used fairly easily.  [`ComponentPublicInstance`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/6aeafef1a548fbe9ea970bb73178cba3608c0fa7/packages/runtime-core/src/componentPublicInstance.ts#L162) also has handful of different generic parameters.

```js
import { ComponentPublicInstance } from 'vue';

let instance: ComponentPublicInstance<{ prop: string }, { value: string }>;
```

Comment: Works great for components but throws a type error for components without a `<script>` tag (e.g. components with `<template>` only).