# Get the type of generic function without invoking the function in typescript

Tags: function, typescript, generics

I have a generic function like this:

```
function foo<T>(val: T) { return val; }
```

I have some types:

```
type StringType = string;
type NumType = number;
```

Now I want to make a reference to the 'foo' function with a given type, but it wont work:

```
const stringFunc = foo<StringType>;
const numFunc = foo<NumType>;
```

Note that I don't want to invoke the 'foo' function, otherwise, I could do:

```
const stringFunc = (val: string) => foo<StringType>(val);
const numFunc = (val: number) => foo<NumType>(val);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: It is not really supported, please see similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50005595/getting-the-return-type-of-a-function-which-uses-generics#answer-50006640

Comment: thanks for the comment, it's unfortunate that it is not possible because I have to make an unnecessary function just for typing purpose :(

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to force the type and don't mind extra typing you can do it like this:

```
const stringFunc: (val: string) => string = foo;
const numFunc: (val: number) => number = foo;
```

But generally applying the type parameter to a generic function is not possible at the moment.

Comment: I was looking for applying the type parameter to a generic function as you have mentioned, but your suggestion actually solved my problem! thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about type casting or invoking some other adhoc generic function?

[TypeScript REPL](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-FQhBBFBydn+DRvfHjn4yfJAVh03sVkWfCdS2hrRXBaI8IIwIU4K2qMHRHwAHTzExwYM0PvBuAWHDfC1KFSIuDwxDOEA0XnET3e65+wMhsPJyPR8X0pCJ5Op9MmTPZ3NL-OF4s7MvGptVhMPpkNl1N8kttsdrs9v2g7DqO46To4zjgrO2R5AUi7Lqu+iGB6Xo+k8-pyIgQahuGB4xhKJ5JimaYZpA155gIhZxIaFyApWTwJo6LrSoo1rpj+radP+DSAQOwK2CBY4TlO+oznOeTmouRGppwQA)

```
function foo<T>(v: T) { return v }

type UnaryFunction<T> = (v: T) => T


// casting
const asStrFoo = foo as UnaryFunction<string> // asStrFoo(v: string): string
const asNumFoo = foo as UnaryFunction<number> // asNumFoo(v: number): number


// identity function
const bind = <T>(f: UnaryFunction<any>): UnaryFunction<T> => f

const strFoo = bind<string>(foo) // strFoo(v: string): string
const numFoo = bind<number>(foo) // numFoo(v: number): number


// function factory
function hoo<T>() { return function foo(v: T) { return v } }
// function hoo<T>() { return (v: T) => v }

const strHoo = hoo<string>() // strHoo(v: string): string
const numHoo = hoo<number>() // numHoo(v: number): number
```

note

```
// This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'UnaryFunction<string>' and 'UnaryFunction<number>' have no overlap.
console.log(strFoo === numFoo) // true
// This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'UnaryFunction<string>' and 'UnaryFunction<number>' have no overlap.
console.log(asStrFoo === asNumFoo) // true
// This condition will always return 'false' since the types '(v: string) => string' and '(v: number) => number' have no overlap.
console.log(strHoo === numHoo) // false
```