# Specify generic inside of "typeof" of function

Tags: typescript

If I have the following function in Typescript

```
function makeArray<T>(obj: T): T[] {
    return [obj];
}
```

I can easily use `typeof` to store it's type:

```
function makeArray<T>(obj: T): T[] {
    return [obj];
}

type ArrayMaker = typeof makeArray;    // <T>(obj: T) => T[]
```

Super handy - but the generic is lost:

```
function makeArray<T>(obj: T): T[] {
    return [obj];
}

type NumberArrayMaker = typeof makeArray<number>;
//                                      ⬆
//                                    "ERROR: ';' expected."
```

This makes sense - functions don't store any generic typing information until called (at which point it's scoped to that single call).  Still, I'd like to be able to store a type that represents a narrowed version of a function.

**Is it possible to make a type from a function which enforces a specific generic?**

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50006640/7742191

Comment: @Pat that question appears to do specifically with return type, not narrowing the scope of the generic across an entire function.