# How to get the return type for specific parameters of a generic function?

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a utility type that takes a signature of a generic function, and its arguments. It should result in the return type of the signature as if it were executed with the provided arguments.

I tried this:

```
type GetReturnType<T extends (...args: any) => any, B> = T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : never;
```

But all generics end up as either `unknown` or `never`.

Some example functions I might want to pass in:

```
function myFn1<T>(x: T) {
    return {
        a: x,
    }
}

function myFn2<T>(x: T) {
    return [x];
}

function myFn3<T>(x: T) {
    if (typeof x == "string") {
        return "yes" as (T extends string ? "yes" : "no");
    } else {
        return "no" as (T extends string ? "yes" : "no");
    }
}
```

And how I'd like `GetReturnType` to be used:

```
type Return1 = GetReturnType<typeof myFn1, [x: number]>; // expected {a: number}
type Return2 = GetReturnType<typeof myFn2, [x: number]>; // expected number[]
type Return3A = GetReturnType<typeof myFn3, [x: number]>; // expected "no"
type Return3B = GetReturnType<typeof myFn3, [x: string]>; // expected "yes"
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=32&ssc=76&pln=29&pc=1#code/PTAEDEFcDsGMBcCWB7aoDOiDm0CG9IAnAU3QCgyAzGBFNAWwE9xoBGAHgBUA%20ACgA8AXKE4BKUAG8yoGaBIFCaKbJWhcw-gBppsgL5l9VGklSgmLAExc%20QkeOWz5RNAG1%20AXQDcBitTgmGZmgAZmsBYTFJHRlESlBeeEYAB2JkOP5QAF5M0AAidHhCRGgsXPto1SdFPMZSXLV0eM5QYn54YmgAE0aCopLQAH4autBhXOhkMu8VXRaAG3RiKNVHYgU0ccmGppa2ju6MQuKsQeH0erGJqYr9QwoyRJTQAHE1gCU1505k4i5d9q6jV4ADpQbhCFh0MJcNBGOJMtw1LDNKAAEKInLNVoAg4gsEQqFIuFZRHFSjEQigN6nanCaDEABuFO89xAVNIkDm8HIjyWH3WrCyL3en0U3xS7F5aTMQVYKLcdMg9AARhT3NxPKA2a0UghiJ1JOpQNAlarCPpeez1hYha94Pyvj9JT9peZoBZ5bYTSq1RqtWAdcQ9QbvWaXO4Hj8rc5ggBBW0i9bi35SuJu4KexU%20wjqzXa-i69oGza5SNPB2KYKohP20XQZPOlKuoIZ0AKw59LC5-27Qv6s65IA)

TypeScript already has a system in place for inferring the generic types of functions. For instance `myFn3("some string")` will infer the first generic argument to be a string and in turn the returned value will be `"yes"`. I'd like to make use of this system when trying to get the return type. [Other questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50005595/getting-the-return-type-of-a-function-which-uses-generics) ask how to do this when the generics are known, but I'd like to know how to do this when the generics are inferred.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Getting the return type of a function which uses generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50005595/getting-the-return-type-of-a-function-which-uses-generics)

Comment: @ysfaran Hmm I'm not sure. I have clarified the difference a bit in the question.

Comment: Hmm though now that I think about it, if the answer on the other question was "it's impossible" that probably applies here as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
const to = <A>(value: A) => ({ value } as const);

type ApplyTo<A> = ReturnType<typeof to<A>>;

const map = <A extends unknown[]>(value: readonly [...A]) => value.map(to) as {
  [K in keyof A]: ApplyTo<A[K]>;
};


type t2 = ReturnType<typeof map<["a", "b", "c"]>>;
// type t2 = [{
//   readonly value: "a";
// }, {
//   readonly value: "b";
// }, {
//   readonly value: "c";
// }]
```

I think this is as close as it gets. It would be better if we could pass `to` as a parameter, but afaik that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The same question, why I can return extra value

```
type RX = { id: number; name: string };
type GetProduct = (name: string) => RX;

const getProduct: GetProduct = (name) => ({ id: 123, name, city: "" });
```

like City here

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDEFcDsGMBcCWB7aoDOiDm0CG9IAnAU3QCgyAzGBFNAWwE9xoBGAHgBUA+ACgA8AXKE4BKUAG8yoGaBIFCaKbJWhcw-gBppsgL5l9VGklSgmLAExc+QkeOWz5RNAG1+AXQDcBitTgmGZmgAZmsBYTFJHRlESlBeeEYAB2JkOP5QAF5M0AAidHhCRGgsXPto1SdFPMZSXLV0eM5QYn54YmgAE0aCopLQAH4autBhXOhkMu8VXRaAG3RiKNVHYgU0ccmGppa2ju6MQuKsQeH0erGJqYr9QzIQUAAlUkg5+HJElKe151Ys7-WnGSxHYn1ScXMbHY0Eg9AARsRCNxuPcwDIAHoDMhggHOCz-Z6A4Gg4FpMxBKww+GI5GeUAPVopBDETqgKkIwgudyo2SY7HA3GKYIAQQJP0UQJSJJSZMhoXZNO4dIZ-CZ7VZm1yPIxWJxhOcwQAQmKiVKwbKgqFesdafSwIziMyNbVztrQJigA)

You can try TS v4.7 [instantiation expression](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7-beta/#instantiation-expressions)