# TypeScript Type Get Return Type of Constrained Function Type Generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Basically, I am trying to find a way to use function types as generic types to find the return type of the function with the constraint that I choose.  However, I'm not sure if it's possible because I don't understand how generic function parameters work in conditional clauses.  Here is what I'm trying currently:

```
type FooFormatter = <S extends string>(input: S) => `foo-${S}`;

type StringFormatter = <S extends string>(input: S, ...args: never) => string;

type ComputeFormatter<Input extends string, T extends StringFormatter> =
    T extends (input: Input, ...args: never) => `${infer $Value}`
        ? $Value
        : never;

type foo = ComputeFormatter<"hey", FooFormatter>; // this is `foo-${string}` but I want "foo-hey"
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9neAnAtgQ2MCSoF4oA8AylBAB5YB2AJgM5S3BICWlA5gHwAUrYArsABcUIgEo8HKAAMAZggC0AEgDeRAL5SA3AFgAUHtCQRTVm2TpM2PIRLkqdBifbdeA4UQA0UAHS+0SNlphSggAN2xxXElGFnYdfV1DaABhOBR+LHMMLCQCAElKDNIKCBp6GNMvABVi+3oiJzM4VGzsSVw9KC6oGrtShx5CtygCjK9fb39A4LCIiWkVVhkrRQA1NAAbPggNTu79gH4oNc3tvf2umfCkeINwaDk4a1T0gQgsy1yAIgALCBAvl54IhmhYchxNFAAPRQqDAH7MeiI6SPJTKCrsDRQABGAhGUAA7mhKMAoF9UX8AUA)

In `ComputeFormatter` I'm trying to check if I can somehow constrain the generic in `T` by overwriting the function's first parameter to the `Input` type.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't know what canonical means in the bounty context but I just meant I don't want low-effort answers.

Comment: Can you tell me how you plan to use ComputerFormatter? Will there be a function that you call that will output the result of ComputeFormatter? Regardless, can you show a full usage example instead of just the type assignment? I ask becuase you can't really do what you're asking without some dirty work arounds. But if your useage is different, there may be a different way to go about this.

Comment: @Kyle It will be complex (e.g. convert text to lowercase, separate by separator then include other generic string). If you're talking about a workaround like this https://tsplay.dev/WKVGZm then it won't work for me.

Comment: I'm basically trying to make my lib feign https://github.com/sno2/feign which does compile-time parsing using complex types to be inclusive in allowing third-party utilities.  Currently, I just brute force the combinator using some ugly stuff https://github.com/sno2/feign/blob/main/utilities.ts

Comment: So none of this will be used by runtime code, only typescript code?

Comment: Yes it will be used at runtime, the compile-time parsing is built using combinator functions which generate the parsers via generics on the functions.  Then you can see the result at compile-time or run it on generic strings and still have nice, but not exact typing.

Comment: Okay. So the issue is that you cannot infer the result of a generic function in typescript (currently). If you can instead move the generic to the type level instead of the function level, then you can infer it. If you show me the gist of the runtime code, then a different solution might be able to be found.

Comment: But I need these generics to be on function-level such that you can construct parsers using regular functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, there is an [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607) merged for TS4.7 for this feature. Of particular relevance to your question...

```js
type Box<T> = ReturnType<typeof makeBox<T>>;  // { value: T }
```

> > This is super close to a solution of #37181. Will it will allow us to do...
> >
> > ```js
> > return { value }; };
> >
> > // Can we do it or something similar? Currently doesn't compile :(
> > type MakeBox<T> = ReturnType<typeof makeBox<T>>
> >
> > // As it now allows us to do (no generics though)
> > const stringMakeBox = makeBox<string>; type MakeBox = ReturnType<typeof stringMakeBox>
> >
> > // And even more relevant to support generics if we can now do: type
> > MakeBox = ReturnType<typeof makeBox<string>>
> > ```
>
> Yes, you can indeed use that pattern to capture a generic return type of a generic function. This is something that previously wasn't possible. I'll update the PR description to include an example.

[Comment here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607)

I can't find anything on whether this works on type aliases for functions, or just works on runtime functions only (inferred with `typeof`), but you can possibly just use the actual runtime implementations and use `typeof` as needed

Here is this working on the [nightly build](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.0-dev.20220302#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9neAnAtgQ2MCSoF4oA8AylBAB5YB2AJgM5S3BICWlA5gHwAUrYArsABcUIgEo8HKAAMAZggC0AEgDeRAL5SA3AFgAUHoDGcSo1gJk6TNgCSKMABsIKCJWAZmx4fERxUGLDj4ympQaPRolCCaUAD0MShwBgDWUMx2js6u7sZ6eqCQIkysbBb+2HiEJORUdAxF7Ny8AsJEADRQAHRdaEhstMKUEABu2OK4kows7Dr6uvnQcnAVAEoQwHxIlAAq4BAE83AyZj5+Vki2Dk4ubsAelAQARAAWECAPHBx6cVBQAHoA-EA), note that you'll still need a runtime implementation, whether or not it actually implements anything is up to you, it could be some mock function that doesn't return anything

```js
type FooFormatter = <S extends string>(input: S) => `foo-${S}`;

const FooFormatterImplementation: FooFormatter = {} as any; //mock implementation

type StringFormatter = <S extends string>(input: S, ...args: never) => string;

type foo = ReturnType<typeof FooFormatterImplementation<"hey">>
//  ^? `type foo = "foo-hey"`
```

##### My two-cents and more (More Post Script stuff)

I highly recommend investigating some of the types they have over at [`type-fest`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest), if you haven't already. Especially

- [`Split`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/split.d.ts)
- Or in general all their [`Change case utilities`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest#change-case),

Reading through the library, it looks like you've got a good sense of types, and I think you may actually be limited by the TS version of Deno.

There are a bunch of workarounds, but I'm not sure if they're really applicable in your usecase.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/50006640/17954209
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62620115/17954209

#### Edit: Workaround with declaration merging and interfaces

**This is not dependent upon TS4.7** Hooray!

```js
type FooFormatter = <S extends string>(input: S) => `foo-${S}`;

type BarFormatter = <S extends string>(input: S) => `bar-${S}`

export interface Formatters {
    FooFormatter: FooFormatter,
    BarFormatter: BarFormatter
}
// then anyone wanting to add a custom formatter, has to modify and reexport the interface,
// this is similiarly done in @react-mui, using module augmentation
// https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

function takeInnerTest<T extends string, FmtKey extends keyof Formatters>(input: T, formatter: FmtKey)
{
    type formattersDiscriminated = {
        [K in keyof Formatters]: Formatters[K]
    }[FmtKey]
    const __mockFunction: formattersDiscriminated = ((...args: any[]) => undefined) as any
    const __mockReturn = __mockFunction(input)
    type String = ReturnType<typeof __mockFunction>
    type ReturnValue = Extract<typeof __mockReturn, String>
    return null! as ReturnValue
}

const foo3 = takeInnerTest("hey", "FooFormatter")
type foo3 = typeof foo3
//  ^?
const foo4 = takeInnerTest("hey", "BarFormatter")
type foo4 = typeof foo4
//  ^?
```

[TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NnQOVw)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the github link but yeah, I need to be able to calculate it for generic function types because I am getting the function type from higher order function generics.  I also tried using the instantiation features to create a new solution although it did not work either https://tsplay.dev/WJ4ekN

Comment: I supposed this might be a good example for what I mean by needing to be able to nest these formatter types in higher-order functions https://tsplay.dev/we4RYW

Comment: @sno2 I went ahead and added an edit to my answer, this uses declaration merging and an interface to expose somewhere for other users to manipulate the possible `Formatters`. Check it out and see it fits your use case.

Comment: Thank you very much @CodyDuong ! Fabulous solution. I was able to modify the code to derive the key of the formatter from the formatter function so now I am able to modify my library to use this technique.  I will award the bounty to you after the 1 day cooldown ends.

Comment: Epic answer. I learned some new things today. Thanks!