# Typescript: Passing a generic class as a generic variable

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to create a derived type from a generic TypeScript class. However, the generic type I'm using is apparently removing the generics from the class and giving a "type [variable] is not a generic" error.

Example below:

```js
class Tester<T extends Record<string, string> = {}> {
  // ...
}

type Test<S extends typeof Tester> = S<{hello: "world"}> // ! error "Type 'S' is not generic."
```

How should something like this be approached in TypeScript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript Type Get Return Type of Constrained Function Type Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71640624/typescript-type-get-return-type-of-constrained-function-type-generics)  Check the first answer.

Comment: On the face of it, what you're asking for is not supported in TypeScript; it would require *higher kinded types* as requested in [ms/TS#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213).  But can you articulate the use case and show examples?  What kinds of things are you imagining being passed in as `S`, other than `typeof Tester` itself?  And `Tester<T>` is structurally independent of `T` which is not good for examples.

Comment: @sno2 indeed, this might provide the functionality that fixes the issue.  Can't be totally sure without running version 4.7. I'll report back when I do.

Comment: @jcalz the use case here is a derived type from a class or array of classes; specifically I am working on endpoint management (creating endpoints and the utilities to call them) ... 

I believe that v4.7 is introducing some tweaks that will make this work better; so Im gonna try that and report back.. Otherwise, i'll provide more use-case information. Thanks for your answer.